# What is the difference between currying and partial application?

Tags: language-agnostic, terminology, definition, currying, partial-application

I quite often see on the Internet various complaints that other peoples examples of currying are not currying, but are actually just partial application.

I've not found a decent explanation of what partial application is, or how it differs from currying. There seems to be a general confusion, with equivalent examples being described as currying in some places, and partial application in others.

Could someone provide me with a definition of both terms, and details of how they differ?

Answer (score 289, accepted):

Currying is converting a single function of *n* arguments into *n* functions with a single argument each. Given the following function:

```
function f(x,y,z) { z(x(y));}
```

When curried, becomes:

```
function f(x) { lambda(y) { lambda(z) { z(x(y)); } } }
```

In order to get the full application of f(x,y,z), you need to do this:

```
f(x)(y)(z);
```

Many functional languages let you write `f x y z`. If you only call `f x y` or *f(x)(y)* then you get a partially-applied function—the return value is a closure of `lambda(z){z(x(y))}` with passed-in the values of x and y to `f(x,y)`.

One way to use partial application is to define functions as partial applications of generalized functions, like **fold**:

```
function fold(combineFunction, accumulator, list) {/* ... */}
function sum     = curry(fold)(lambda(accum,e){e+accum}))(0);
function length  = curry(fold)(lambda(accum,_){1+accum})(empty-list);
function reverse = curry(fold)(lambda(accum,e){concat(e,accum)})(empty-list);

/* ... */
@list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
sum(list) //returns 10
@f = fold(lambda(accum,e){e+accum}) //f = lambda(accumulator,list) {/*...*/}
f(0,list) //returns 10
@g = f(0) //same as sum
g(list)  //returns 10
```

Comment: You're saying that partial application is when you curry a function, and use some, but not all of the resulting functions?

Comment: more or less, yes. If you only supply a subset of the arguments, you'll get back a function that accepts the rest of the arguments

Comment: Would changing a function f(a, b, c, d) to g(a, b) count as partial application? Or is it only when applied to curried functions? Sorry to be a pain, but I'm angling for an explicit answer here.

Comment: g(a,b) would be a partial application only if g == f(a,b) and g(a',b') == f(a,b,a',b'). Partial application has to go in the order the arguments are specified

Comment: But the same is not true for currying? I could translate f(a, b, c) into g(c) -> h(a) -> i(b), and that would still be currying? And then I couldn't use these functions for partial application?

Comment: If you re-arranged the arguments like that, I guess it can still be considered currying. You can then go ahead and call g(x) and get back a function that accepts "a" and then "b" as arguments. Or call "g(c)(a)" and get back a function that accepts "b".

Comment: Anent your statement: _Currying is converting a single function of n arguments into n functions with a single argument each_ - I understand just the opposite; currying is taking multiple, one-argument functions, then _composing_ a multiple-argument function.

Whereas a partially applied function is creating from a function that accepts multiple arguments a function that requires fewer, e.g.

`var Add = function(a,b) { return a + b; } var AddOne = partial(Add, 1);`

Can you cite sources for your explanation/understanding?

Here is one I read: http://bit.ly/CurryingVersusPartialApplication

Comment: @Jason: Your source says the same thing that I do—in its example, it takes a pre-curried multi-argument function defined using "define/curried" and re-composes it back uisng partial application. For a clearer definition of currying and partial application that are the same as mine, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying .

Comment: @Mark: I guess this is just one of those concepts that brings out the pedant in me - but an appeal to authoritative sources does little to satisfy, since they all seem to point to one another. Wikipedia is hardly what I consider an authoritative source, but I understand that it's hard to find much else. Suffice it to say that I think we both know that of which we speak and the power thereof, regardless of whether or not we can agree (or disagree) on the particulars of the vernacular! :) Thanks Mark!

Comment: @JasonBunting, Regarding your first comment, what you were talking about is *decurrying*. Currying is taking a multi-arg function as input and returning a chain of 1-arg functions as output. De-currying is taking a chain of 1-arg functions as input and returning a multi-arg function as output. As elaborated on http://stackoverflow.com/a/23438430/632951

Comment: "Currying is converting a single function of n arguments into n functions with a single argument each". Isn't changing a function signature f(a, b, c, d) to f(a)(b, c)(d) also currying? Do the resulting functions _have_ to have a single argument each?

Answer (score 185):

The easiest way to see how they differ is to consider a **real example**. Let's assume that we have a function `Add` which takes 2 numbers as input and returns a number as output, e.g. `Add(7, 5)` returns `12`. In this case:

- **Partial applying** the function `Add` with a value `7` will give us a new function as output. That function itself takes 1 number as input and outputs a number. As such:

  ```
  Partial(Add, 7); // returns a function f2 as output

                   // f2 takes 1 number as input and returns a number as output
  ```

  So we can do this:

  ```
  f2 = Partial(Add, 7);
  f2(5); // returns 12;
         // f2(7)(5) is just a syntactic shortcut
  ```
- **Currying** the function `Add` will give us a new function as output. That function itself takes 1 number as input and outputs *yet* another new function. That third function then takes 1 number as input and returns a number as output. As such:

  ```
  Curry(Add); // returns a function f2 as output

              // f2 takes 1 number as input and returns a function f3 as output
              // i.e. f2(number) = f3

              // f3 takes 1 number as input and returns a number as output
              // i.e. f3(number) = number
  ```

  So we can do this:

  ```
  f2 = Curry(Add);
  f3 = f2(7);
  f3(5); // returns 12
  ```

In other words, "currying" and "partial application" are two totally different functions. **Currying takes exactly 1 input, whereas partial application takes 2 (or more) inputs.**

Even though they both return a function as output, the returned functions are of totally different forms as demonstrated above.

Comment: Partial application transforms a function from `n-ary` to `(x - n)-ary`, currying from `n-ary` to `n * 1-ary`. A partially applied function has a **reduced scope** (of application), that is, `Add7` is less expressive than `Add`. A curried function on the other hand is as expressive as the original function.

Comment: I believe the more distinctive trait is when we curry f(x,y,z)=>R, we get f(x) which returns g(y)=>h(z)=>R, each consuming a single argument; but when we partially apply f(x,y,z) as f(x) we get g(y,z)=>R, that is, with two arguments. If not for that trait, we could say that currying is like partial application to 0 arguments, thus leaving all arguments unbound; however in reality f() partially applied to 0 arguments is a function consuming 3 args at once, unlike curried f().

Comment: Once again the correct answer isn't the first or the most voted: The simple explanation of the signature of curry vs. partial at the end of this answer is really the easiest way to resolve the question.

Comment: What does the comment `f2(7)(5) is just a syntactic shortcut` mean?  (I know very little.)  Doesn't `f2` already contain/"know about" 7?

Comment: @Pacerier, is there a `curry` implementation somewhere (don't think it's in `functools`)

Comment: I am having a hard time with curry vs partial because in functional language, such as OCaml, there is no difference between currying and partial application. This holds because in functional languages, functions are first-class objects.

Comment: So how does currying work in case of variable number of arguments, e.g. in Common Lisp: `(defun foo (&rest args) ...)`. This would result in an infinite number of curried 1 argument functions, yes? I could not find a Common Lisp implementation of `curry` and would be curious.

Answer (score 58):

Note: this was taken from [F# Basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee336127.aspx) an excellent introductory article for .NET developers getting into functional programming.

> Currying means breaking a function with many arguments into a series
>   of functions that each take one argument and ultimately produce the
>   same result as the original function. Currying is probably the most
>   challenging topic for developers new to functional programming, particularly because it
>   is often confused with partial application. You can see both at work
>   in this example:
>
> ```
> let multiply x y = x * y    
> let double = multiply 2
> let ten = double 5
> ```
>
> Right away, you should see behavior that is different from most
>   imperative languages. The second statement creates a new function
>   called double by passing one argument to a function that takes two.
>   The result is a function that accepts one int argument and yields the
>   same output as if you had called multiply with x equal to 2 and y
>   equal to that argument. In terms of behavior, it’s the same as this
>   code:
>
> ```
> let double2 z = multiply 2 z
> ```
>
> Often, people mistakenly say that multiply is curried to form double.
>   But this is only somewhat true. The multiply function is curried, but
>   that happens when it is defined because functions in F# are curried by
>   default. When the double function is created, it’s more accurate to
>   say that the multiply function is partially applied.
>
> The multiply function is really a series of two functions. The first
>   function takes one int argument and returns another function,
>   effectively binding x to a specific value. This function also accepts
>   an int argument that you can think of as the value to bind to y. After
>   calling this second function, x and y are both bound, so the result is
>   the product of x and y as defined in the body of double.
>
> To create double, the first function in the chain of multiply
>   functions is evaluated to partially apply multiply. The resulting
>   function is given the name double. When double is evaluated, it uses
>   its argument along with the partially applied value to create the
>   result.

Answer (score 38):

Interesting question. After a bit of searching, ["Partial Function Application is not currying"](https://web.archive.org/web/20161023205431/http://www.uncarved.com/articles/not_currying) gave the best explanation I found. I can't say that the *practical* difference is particularly obvious to me, but then I'm not an FP expert...

Another useful-looking page (which I confess I haven't fully read yet) is ["Currying and Partial Application with Java Closures"](http://markmahieu.blogspot.com/2007/12/currying-and-partial-application-with.html).

It does look like this is widely-confused pair of terms, mind you.

Comment: Interesting links, although they do offer conflicting ideas of what currying is.

Comment: The first link is spot-on about the differences. Here's another one I found useful: http://bit.ly/CurryingVersusPartialApplication

Comment: Currying is to do with tuples (turning a function that takes a tuple argument into one that takes n separate arguments, and vice versa). Partial application is the ability to apply a function to some arguments, yielding a new function for the remaining arguments.   It is easy to remember if you just think currying == to do with tuples.

Comment: @Jon links you posted are informative, but it will be better to expand your answer and add some more info here.

Comment: @Zaheer: This answer is over 6 years old, and the other answers already cover it. I don't think there's much to be gained from expanding this now.

Comment: @Jon see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275464/why-was-my-flag-for-a-link-only-answer-from-2008-declined

Comment: Can't believe you got 20 upvotes for a couple links and an admission you don't really know the difference between curry and partial application. Well played, sir.

Comment: Someone's mad they're not Jon Skeet

Answer (score 18):

I have answered this in another thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/12846865/1685865 .  In short, partial function application is about fixing some arguments of a given multivariable function to yield another function with fewer arguments, while Currying is about turning a function of N arguments into a unary function which returns a unary function...[An example of Currying is shown at the end of this post.]

Currying is mostly of theoretical interest: one can express computations using only unary functions (i.e. *every* function is unary). In practice and as a byproduct, it is a technique which can make many useful (but not all) partial functional applications trivial, if the language has curried functions. Again, it is not the only means to implement partial applications. So you could encounter scenarios where partial application is done in other way, but people are mistaking it as Currying.

*(Example of Currying)*

In practice one would not just write

```
lambda x: lambda y: lambda z: x + y + z
```

or the equivalent javascript

```
function (x) { return function (y){ return function (z){ return x + y + z }}}
```

instead of

```
lambda x, y, z: x + y + z
```

for the sake of Currying.

Comment: Would you say that currying is a specific case of partial application then?

Comment: @SpoonMeiser, No, currying is not a specific case of partial application: A partial application of a 2-input function is not the same as currying the function. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23438430/632951 .

Answer (score 16):

Currying is a function of **one** argument which takes a function `f` and returns a new function `h`. Note that `h` takes an argument from `X` and returns a *function* that maps `Y` to `Z`:

```
curry(f) = h 
f: (X x Y) -> Z 
h: X -> (Y -> Z)
```

Partial application is a function of **two(or more)** arguments which takes a function `f` and one or more additional arguments to `f` and returns a new function `g`:

```
part(f, 2) = g
f: (X x Y) -> Z 
g: Y -> Z
```

The confusion arises because with a two-argument function the following equality holds:

```
partial(f, a) = curry(f)(a)
```

Both sides will yield the same one-argument function.

The equality is not true for higher arity functions because in this case currying will return a one-argument function, whereas partial application will return a multiple-argument function.

The difference is also in the behavior, whereas currying transforms the whole original function recursively(once for each argument), partial application is just a one step replacement.

Source: [Wikipedia Currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

Answer (score 13):

## Simple answer

**Curry:** lets you call a function, splitting it in multiple calls, providing *one* argument per-call.

**Partial:** lets you call a function, splitting it in multiple calls, providing *multiple* arguments per-call.

---

## Simple hints

Both allow you to call a function providing less arguments (or, better, providing them cumulatively). Actually both of them bind (at each call) a specific value to specific arguments of the function.

The real difference can be seen when the function has more than 2 arguments.

---

## Simple e(c)(sample)

*(in Javascript)*

We want to run the following `process` function on different `subject`s (e.g. let's say our subjects are `"subject1"` and `"foobar"` strings):

```
function process(context, successCallback, errorCallback, subject) {...}
```

why always passing the arguments, like context and the callbacks, if they will be always the same?

Just bind some values for the the function:

```
processSubject = _.partial(process, my_context, my_success, my_error)
// assign fixed values to the first 3 arguments of the `process` function
```

and call it on *subject1* and *foobar*, omitting the repetition of the first 3 arguments, with:

```
processSubject('subject1');
processSubject('foobar');
```

Comfy, isn't it?

---

With *currying* you'd instead need to pass one argument per time

```
curriedProcess = _.curry(process);   // make the function curry-able
processWithBoundedContext = curriedProcess(my_context);
processWithCallbacks = processWithBoundedContext(my_success)(my_error); // note: these are two sequential calls

result1 = processWithCallbacks('subject1');
// same as: process(my_context, my_success, my_error, 'subject1');

result2 = processWithCallbacks('foobar'); 
// same as: process(my_context, my_success, my_error, 'foobar');
```

#### Disclaimer

I skipped all the academic/mathematical explanation. Cause I don't know it. Maybe it helped

---

**EDIT:**

As added by ***@basickarl***, a further slight difference in use of the two functions (see *Lodash* for examples) is that:

- `partial` returns a pre-cooked function that **can be called once with the missing argument(s)** and return the final result;
- while `curry` **is being called multiple times (one for each argument)**, returning a pre-cooked function each time; except in the case of calling with the last argument, that will return the actual result from the processing of *all* the arguments.

---

## With ES6:

here's a [quick example](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/functional-programming-higher-order-function-hof-aaa46bb444bb#0760) of how immediate Currying and Partial-application are in ECMAScript 6.

```
const partialSum = math => (eng, geo) => math + eng + geo;
const curriedSum = math => eng => geo => math + eng + geo;
```

Answer (score 10):

The difference between curry and partial application can be best illustrated through this following JavaScript example:

```
function f(x, y, z) {
    return x + y + z;
}

var partial = f.bind(null, 1);

6 === partial(2, 3);
```

Partial application results in a function of smaller arity; in the example above, `f` has an arity of 3 while `partial` only has an arity of 2. More importantly, a partially applied function would **return the result right away upon being invoke**, not another function down the currying chain. So if you are seeing something like `partial(2)(3)`, it's not partial application in actuality.

Further reading:

- [Functional Programming in 5 minutes](http://slid.es/gsklee/functional-programming-in-5-minutes)
- [Currying: Contrast with Partial Function Application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Contrast_with_partial_function_application)

Comment: " a partially applied function would return the result right away upon being invoke" - that's not correct, is it? when I partially apply a function, that expression returns a function, not "a result". Ok, you probably meant that this latter function, when called with the remaining arguments, returns the result, unlike digging one step down into currying. But no one actually says you have to specify all the remaining arguments: you can partially-apply the result of partial application, and that will once again be a function, not a "result"

Answer (score 5):

I had this question a lot while learning and have since been asked it many times. The simplest way I can describe the difference is that both are the same :) Let me explain...there are obviously differences.

Both partial application and currying involve supplying arguments to a function, perhaps not all at once. A fairly canonical example is adding two numbers. In pseudocode (actually JS without keywords), the base function may be the following:

```
add = (x, y) => x + y
```

If I wanted an "addOne" function, I could partially apply it or curry it:

```
addOneC = curry(add, 1)
addOneP = partial(add, 1)
```

Now using them is clear:

```
addOneC(2) #=> 3
addOneP(2) #=> 3
```

So what's the difference? Well, it's subtle, but partial application involves supplying some arguments and the returned function will then *execute the main function upon next invocation* whereas currying will keep waiting till it has all the arguments necessary:

```
curriedAdd = curry(add) # notice, no args are provided
addOne = curriedAdd(1) # returns a function that can be used to provide the last argument
addOne(2) #=> returns 3, as we want

partialAdd = partial(add) # no args provided, but this still returns a function
addOne = partialAdd(1) # oops! can only use a partially applied function once, so now we're trying to add one to an undefined value (no second argument), and we get an error
```

In short, use partial application to prefill some values, knowing that the next time you call the method, it will execute, leaving undefined all unprovided arguments; use currying when you want to continually return a partially-applied function as many times as necessary to fulfill the function signature. One final contrived example:

```
curriedAdd = curry(add)
curriedAdd()()()()()(1)(2) # ugly and dumb, but it works

partialAdd = partial(add)
partialAdd()()()()()(1)(2) # second invocation of those 7 calls fires it off with undefined parameters
```

Hope this helps!

UPDATE: Some languages or lib implementations will allow you to pass an arity (total number of arguments in final evaluation) to the partial application implementation which may conflate my two descriptions into a confusing mess...but at that point, the two techniques are largely interchangeable.

Answer (score 5):

A lot of people here do not address this properly, and no one has talked about overlaps.

### Simple answer

**Currying:** Lets you call a function, splitting it in multiple calls, providing one argument per-call.

**Partial Application:** Lets you call a function, splitting it in multiple calls, providing multiple arguments per-call.

> One of the significant differences between the two is that a call to a
> partially applied function returns the result right away, not another
> function down the currying chain; this distinction can be illustrated
> clearly for functions whose arity is greater than two.

What does that mean? That means that there are max two calls for a partial function. Currying has as many as the amount of arguments. If the currying function only has two arguments, then it is essentially the same as a partial function.

### Examples

**Partial Application and Currying**

```
function bothPartialAndCurry(firstArgument) {
    return function(secondArgument) {
        return firstArgument + secondArgument;
    }
}

const partialAndCurry = bothPartialAndCurry(1);
const result = partialAndCurry(2);
```

**Partial Application**

```
function partialOnly(firstArgument, secondArgument) {
    return function(thirdArgument, fourthArgument, fifthArgument) {
        return firstArgument + secondArgument + thirdArgument + fourthArgument + fifthArgument;
    }
}

const partial = partialOnly(1, 2);
const result = partial(3, 4, 5);
```

**Currying**

```
function curryOnly(firstArgument) {
    return function(secondArgument) {
        return function(thirdArgument) {
            return function(fourthArgument ) {
                return function(fifthArgument) {
                    return firstArgument + secondArgument + thirdArgument + fourthArgument + fifthArgument;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

const curryFirst = curryOnly(1);
const currySecond = curryFirst(2);
const curryThird = currySecond(3);
const curryFourth = curryThird(4);
const result = curryFourth(5);

// or...

const result = curryOnly(1)(2)(3)(4)(5);
```

### Naming conventions

*I'll write this when I have time, which is soon.*

Answer (score 4):

For me partial application must create a new function where the used arguments are completely integrated into the resulting function.

Most functional languages implement currying by returning a closure: do not evaluate under lambda when partially applied. So, for partial application to be interesting, we need to make a difference between currying and partial application and consider partial application as currying plus evaluation under lambda.

Answer (score 4):

I could be very wrong here, as I don't have a strong background in theoretical mathematics or functional programming, but from my brief foray into FP, it seems that currying tends to turn a function of N arguments into N functions of one argument, whereas partial application [in practice] works better with variadic functions with an indeterminate number of arguments. I know some of the examples in previous answers defy this explanation, but it has helped me the most to separate the concepts. Consider this example (written in CoffeeScript for succinctness, my apologies if it confuses further, but please ask for clarification, if needed):

```
# partial application
partial_apply = (func) ->
  args = [].slice.call arguments, 1
  -> func.apply null, args.concat [].slice.call arguments

sum_variadic = -> [].reduce.call arguments, (acc, num) -> acc + num

add_to_7_and_5 = partial_apply sum_variadic, 7, 5

add_to_7_and_5 10 # returns 22
add_to_7_and_5 10, 11, 12 # returns 45

# currying
curry = (func) ->
  num_args = func.length
  helper = (prev) ->
    ->
      args = prev.concat [].slice.call arguments
      return if args.length < num_args then helper args else func.apply null, args
  helper []

sum_of_three = (x, y, z) -> x + y + z
curried_sum_of_three = curry sum_of_three
curried_sum_of_three 4 # returns a function expecting more arguments
curried_sum_of_three(4)(5) # still returns a function expecting more arguments
curried_sum_of_three(4)(5)(6) # returns 15
curried_sum_of_three 4, 5, 6 # returns 15
```

This is obviously a contrived example, but notice that partially applying a function that accepts any number of arguments allows us to execute a function but with some preliminary data. Currying a function is similar but allows us to execute an N-parameter function in pieces until, but only until, all N parameters are accounted for.

Again, this is my take from things I've read. If anyone disagrees, I would appreciate a comment as to why rather than an immediate downvote. Also, if the CoffeeScript is difficult to read, please visit coffeescript.org, click "try coffeescript" and paste in my code to see the compiled version, which may (hopefully) make more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to assume most people who ask this question are already familiar with the basic concepts so their is no need to talk about that.  It's the overlap that is the confusing part.

You might be able to fully use the concepts, but you understand them together as this pseudo-atomic amorphous conceptual blur.  What is missing is knowing where the boundary between them is.

Instead of defining what each one is, it's easier to highlight just their differences—the boundary.

*Currying* is when you **define** the function.

*Partial Application* is when you **call** the function.

*Application* is math-speak for calling a function.

**Partial** application requires calling a curried function and getting a function as the return type.

Answer (score 3):

There are other great answers here but I believe this example (as per my understanding) in Java might be of benefit to some people:

```java
public static <A,B,X> Function< B, X > partiallyApply( BiFunction< A, B, X > aBiFunction, A aValue ){
    return b -> aBiFunction.apply( aValue, b );
}

public static <A,X> Supplier< X > partiallyApply( Function< A, X > aFunction, A aValue ){
    return () -> aFunction.apply( aValue );
}

public static <A,B,X> Function<  A, Function< B, X >  > curry( BiFunction< A, B, X > bif ){
    return a -> partiallyApply( bif, a );
}
```

**So currying gives you a one-argument function to create functions, where partial-application creates a wrapper function that hard codes one or more arguments.**

If you want to copy&paste, the following is noisier but friendlier to work with since the types are more lenient:

```java
public static <A,B,X> Function< ? super B, ? extends X > partiallyApply( final BiFunction< ? super A, ? super B, X > aBiFunction, final A aValue ){
    return b -> aBiFunction.apply( aValue, b );
}

public static <A,X> Supplier< ? extends X > partiallyApply( final Function< ? super A, X > aFunction, final A aValue ){
    return () -> aFunction.apply( aValue );
}

public static <A,B,X> Function<  ? super A,  Function< ? super B, ? extends X >  > curry( final BiFunction< ? super A, ? super B, ? extends X > bif ){
    return a -> partiallyApply( bif, a );
}
```

Comment: The following gave me the key insight:
"So currying gives you a one-argument function to create functions, where partial-application creates a wrapper function that hard codes one or more arguments."

Answer (score 2):

#### Currying

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)

> Currying is the technique of converting a function that takes multiple arguments into a sequence of functions that each takes a single argument.

Example

```js
const add = (a, b) => a + b

const addC = (a) => (b) => a + b // curried function. Where C means curried
```

#### Partial application

Article [Just Enough FP: Partial Application](https://kyleshevlin.com/just-enough-fp-partial-application)

> Partial application is the act of applying some, but not all, of the arguments to a function and returning a new function awaiting the rest of the arguments. These applied arguments are stored in closure and remain available to any of the partially applied returned functions in the future.

Example

```js
const add = (a) => (b) => a + b

const add3 = add(3) // add3 is a partially applied function

add3(5) // 8
```

#### The difference is

1. `currying` is a technique (pattern)
2. `partial application` is a function with some predefined arguments (like `add3` from the previous example)

Answer (score 1):

In writing this, I confused currying and uncurrying.  They are inverse transformations on functions.  It really doesn't matter what you call which, as long as you get what the transformation and its inverse represent.

Uncurrying isn't defined very clearly (or rather, there are "conflicting" definitions that all capture the spirit of the idea).  Basically, it means turning a function that takes multiple arguments into a function that takes a single argument.  For example,

```
(+) :: Int -> Int -> Int
```

Now, how do you turn this into a function that takes a single argument?  You cheat, of course!

```
plus :: (Int, Int) -> Int
```

Notice that plus now takes a single argument (that is composed of two things).  Super!

What's the point of this?  Well, if you have a function that takes two arguments, and you have a pair of arguments, it is nice to know that you can apply the function to the arguments, and still get what you expect.  And, in fact, the plumbing to do it already exists, so that you don't have to do things like explicit pattern matching.  All you have to do is:

```
(uncurry (+)) (1,2)
```

So what is partial function application?  It is a different way to turn a function in two arguments into a function with one argument.  It works differently though.  Again, let's take (+) as an example.  How might we turn it into a function that takes a single Int as an argument?  We cheat!

```
((+) 0) :: Int -> Int
```

That's the function that adds zero to any Int.

```
((+) 1) :: Int -> Int
```

adds 1 to any Int.  Etc.  In each of these cases, (+) is "partially applied".