# What is memoization and how can I use it in Python?

Tags: python, memoization

I just started Python and I've got no idea what [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) is and how to use it. Also, may I have a simplified example?

Comment: When the second sentence of the relevant wikipedia article contains the phrase "mutually-recursive descent parsing[1] in a general top-down parsing algorithm[2][3] that accommodates ambiguity and left recursion in polynomial time and space," I think it is entirely appropriate to ask SO what is going on.

Comment: @Clueless: That phrase is preceded by "Memoization has also been used in other contexts (and for purposes other than speed gains), such as in". So it's just a list of examples (and need not be understood); it's not part of the explanation of memoization.

Comment: Here is a good explanation with attached examples of memoization and how to incorporate it into a decorator: http://www.pycogsci.info/?p=221

Comment: New link to pdf file, since pycogsci.info is down: http://people.ucsc.edu/~abrsvn/NLTK_parsing_demos.pdf

Comment: You can look at my blog post at u8y7541.github.io/blog_posts/lambdas_recursion_memoizing.html

Comment: seeing how many people answered and are still answering this question makes be a believer in  the "BIKE SHED EFFECT"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_triviality

Comment: @A_P actually, at the time you wrote that, all but one of the 13 answers were 5 years old (2014), and the most recent one 3 years old (2016). Not sure that counts as "are still answering". The answer I posted just now adds speed considerations that I didn't see in other answers yet and does not implement a new method or anything. There are certainly examples of the phenomenon you're describing but I'm not sure this is it.

Answer (score 433):

Memoization effectively refers to remembering ("memoization" → "memorandum" → to be remembered) results of method calls based on the method inputs and then returning the remembered result rather than computing the result again. You can think of it as a cache for method results. For further details, see page 387 for the definition in ***Introduction To Algorithms*** (3e), Cormen et al.

A simple example for computing factorials using memoization in Python would be something like this:

```
factorial_memo = {}
def factorial(k):
    if k < 2: return 1
    if k not in factorial_memo:
        factorial_memo[k] = k * factorial(k-1)
    return factorial_memo[k]
```

You can get more complicated and encapsulate the memoization process into a class:

```
class Memoize:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
        self.memo = {}
    def __call__(self, *args):
        if not args in self.memo:
            self.memo[args] = self.f(*args)
        #Warning: You may wish to do a deepcopy here if returning objects
        return self.memo[args]
```

Then:

```
def factorial(k):
    if k < 2: return 1
    return k * factorial(k - 1)

factorial = Memoize(factorial)
```

A feature known as "[decorators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/)" was added in Python 2.4 which allow you to now simply write the following to accomplish the same thing:

```
@Memoize
def factorial(k):
    if k < 2: return 1
    return k * factorial(k - 1)
```

The [Python Decorator Library](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary) has a similar decorator called [`memoized`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize) that is slightly more robust than the `Memoize` class shown here.

Comment: I test your two examples in IPython's %timeit. When I use the dictionary (the first example) most of the time I get the first calls executed faster than the memorized second calls. Could you check in your system too? There is a great speed-ups (up to 40X) when I tested the second example. Also could you tell me how to access self.memo name later when the execution is finished?

Comment: OK, please ignore the first part of my question because IPython's timeit makes multiple calls while timing the execution of a function. However the self.memo part is still valid :)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. The Memoize class is an elegant solution which can easily be applied to existing code without needing much refactoring.

Comment: The Memoize class solution is buggy, it will not work the same as the `factorial_memo`, because the `factorial` inside `def factorial` still calls the old unmemoize `factorial`.

Comment: I think @dlutxx has a point. The first version can compute, say, the 50th Fibonacci number quickly *the first time*, whereas the second version with Memoize can't.

Comment: By the way, you can also write `if k not in factorial_memo:`, which reads better than `if not k in factorial_memo:`.

Comment: @adamsmith: I checked that the factorial inside def factorial uses the memoized version.

Comment: Should really do this as a decorator.

Comment: Be careful to make a deep copy if you're going to mutate the output otherwise you will inadvertently mutate your cache.

Comment: can `memoize` in python handle recursive functions?

Comment: @JacksonTale: The example given shows memoizing a recursive function!

Comment: I don't see why the factorial function would be profitable in the first call. It may be profitable in the subsequent calls.

Comment: Theres a rule that really ought be stated about Memoization. Any function can be memoized, on the condition that 1) Its deterministic, and 2) There are no side effects coming in or out of the function. In other words , if the function is not setting , or relying on values outside what it returns and what  goes in the brackets, you can memoize. If this isn't true, expect trouble. Avoiding side effects is generally good programming (And mandatory in true functional languages like haskel) and will save you a hell of a lot of heartache debugging. But its not always OO compatible, so choose wisely.

Comment: But in the third block you are not passing value for `k`?

Comment: Does this even work?  `args` is a list and you can't put a list in a dictionary key, right?

Comment: @durden2.0 I know this is an old comment, but `args` is a tuple. `def some_function(*args)` makes args a tuple.

Comment: Just curious, in this case, when all the processes are done, how would one clear the cached data?

Comment: Regarding the argument about the speedup on the first run with recursive functions: This only works because `factorial = Memoize(factorial)` overwrites the name `factorial` with the memoized function. `fn = Memoize(factorial)` would not speed up calls to `fn` the first time.

Comment: `if not args in self.memo` gives `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. Edit: Nevermind, one of my arguments were not hashable ‍♂️

Answer (score 382):

### `functools.cache` decorator:

Python 3.9 released a new function [`functools.cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache). It caches in memory the result of a function called with a particular set of arguments, which is memoization. It's easy to use:

```python
import functools
import time

@functools.cache
def calculate_double(num):
    time.sleep(1) # sleep for 1 second to simulate a slow calculation
    return num * 2
```

The first time you call `caculate_double(5)`, it will take a second and return 10. The second time you call the function with the same argument `calculate_double(5)`, it will return 10 instantly.

Adding the `cache` decorator ensures that if the function has been called recently for a particular value, it will not recompute that value, but use a cached previous result. In this case, it leads to a tremendous speed improvement, while the code is not cluttered with the details of caching.

(**Edit**: the previous example calculated a fibonacci number using recursion, but I changed the example to prevent confusion, hence the old comments.)

### `functools.lru_cache` decorator:

If you need to support older versions of Python, [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) works in Python 3.2+. By default, it only caches the 128 most recently used calls, but you can set the `maxsize` to `None` to indicate that the cache should never expire:

```python
@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def calculate_double(num):
    # etc
```

---

Comment: @Andyk Default Py3 recursion limit is 1000. The first time `fib` is called, it will need to recur down to the base case before memoization can happen. So, your behavior is just about expected.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it caches only until the process is not killed, right? Or does it cache regardless of whether the process is killed? Like, say I restart my system - will the cached results still be cached?

Comment: @Kristada673 Yes, it's stored in the process' memory, not on disk.

Comment: Does this introduce significantly more latency than implementing an ad-hoc memoization routine?

Comment: @PranavVempati No, why would it?

Comment: Note that this speeds up even the first run of the function, since it's a recursive function and is caching its own intermediate results.  Might be good to illustrate a non-recursive function that's just inherently slow to make it clearer to dummies like me.  :D

Comment: Neat: `fib.cache_info()` might print something cool like `CacheInfo(hits=400, misses=401, maxsize=None, currsize=401)`

Comment: This worked VERY well for my use case where I had to keep grabbing a large data set over and over again (using `read_csv` and `read_sql` to grab two dataframes). Caching it using this method resulted in a speed improvement of about 27 times. Thanks!

Comment: New in 3.9 is [`functools.cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache) which is (in [cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/functools.py#L653) at least) a wrapper for `lru_cache(maxsize=None)` but with a shorter name.

Answer (score 64):

The other answers cover what it is quite well. I'm not repeating that. Just some points that might be useful to you.

Usually, memoisation is an operation you can apply on any function that computes something (expensive) and returns a value. Because of this, it's often implemented as a [decorator](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/). The implementation is straightforward and it would be something like this

```
memoised_function = memoise(actual_function)
```

or expressed as a decorator

```
@memoise
def actual_function(arg1, arg2):
   #body
```

Answer (score 28):

I've found this extremely useful

```py
from functools import wraps


def memoize(function):    
    memo = {}
        
    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(*args):

        # add the new key to dict if it doesn't exist already  
        if args not in memo:
            memo[args] = function(*args)

        return memo[args]

    return wrapper
    
    
@memoize
def fibonacci(n):
    if n < 2: return n
    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)
    
fibonacci(25)
```

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps for why one should use `functools.wraps`.

Comment: Do I need to manually clear the `memo` so that memory is freed?

Comment: The whole idea is that the results are stored inside memo within a session. I.e. nothing are being cleared as it is

Comment: is "args not in memo" literally enumerating the memo list of keys and checking if args matches? or is actually using the underlying dictionary and checking if the entry hashed(args) is present in memo dictionary's underlying array? if its the former then does this code run faster if we use defaultdictionaries to insist on checking the hash?

Answer (score 20):

Memoization is keeping the results of expensive calculations and returning the cached result rather than continuously recalculating it.

Here's an example:

```
def doSomeExpensiveCalculation(self, input):
    if input not in self.cache:
        <do expensive calculation>
        self.cache[input] = result
    return self.cache[input]
```

A more complete description can be found in the [wikipedia entry on memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

Answer (score 20):

Let's not forget the built-in `hasattr` function, for those who want to hand-craft. That way you can keep the mem cache inside the function definition (as opposed to a global).

```
def fact(n):
    if not hasattr(fact, 'mem'):
        fact.mem = {1: 1}
    if not n in fact.mem:
        fact.mem[n] = n * fact(n - 1)
    return fact.mem[n]
```

Comment: This seems like a very expensive idea.  For every n, it not only caches the results for n, but also for 2 ... n-1.

Answer (score 6):

Memoization is basically saving the results of past operations done with recursive algorithms in order to reduce the need to traverse the recursion tree if the same calculation is required at a later stage.

see http://scriptbucket.wordpress.com/2012/12/11/introduction-to-memoization/

Fibonacci Memoization example in Python:

```
fibcache = {}
def fib(num):
    if num in fibcache:
        return fibcache[num]
    else:
        fibcache[num] = num if num < 2 else fib(num-1) + fib(num-2)
        return fibcache[num]
```

Comment: For more performance pre-seed your fibcache with the first few known values, then you can take the extra logic for handling them out of the 'hot path' of the code.

Answer (score 5):

Memoization is the conversion of functions into data structures. Usually one wants the conversion to occur incrementally and lazily (on demand of a given domain element--or "key"). In lazy functional languages, this lazy conversion can happen automatically, and thus memoization can be implemented without (explicit) side-effects.

Answer (score 5):

Well I should answer the first part first: what's memoization?

It's just a method to trade memory for time. Think of [Multiplication Table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_table).

Using mutable object as default value in Python is usually considered bad. But if use it wisely, it can actually be useful to implement a `memoization`.

Here's an example adapted from http://docs.python.org/2/faq/design.html#why-are-default-values-shared-between-objects

Using a mutable `dict` in the function definition, the intermediate computed results can be cached (e.g. when calculating `factorial(10)` after calculate `factorial(9)`, we can reuse all the intermediate results)

```
def factorial(n, _cache={1:1}):    
    try:            
        return _cache[n]           
    except IndexError:
        _cache[n] = factorial(n-1)*n
        return _cache[n]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution that will work with list or dict type arguments without whining:

```
def memoize(fn):
    """returns a memoized version of any function that can be called
    with the same list of arguments.
    Usage: foo = memoize(foo)"""

    def handle_item(x):
        if isinstance(x, dict):
            return make_tuple(sorted(x.items()))
        elif hasattr(x, '__iter__'):
            return make_tuple(x)
        else:
            return x

    def make_tuple(L):
        return tuple(handle_item(x) for x in L)

    def foo(*args, **kwargs):
        items_cache = make_tuple(sorted(kwargs.items()))
        args_cache = make_tuple(args)
        if (args_cache, items_cache) not in foo.past_calls:
            foo.past_calls[(args_cache, items_cache)] = fn(*args,**kwargs)
        return foo.past_calls[(args_cache, items_cache)]
    foo.past_calls = {}
    foo.__name__ = 'memoized_' + fn.__name__
    return foo
```

Note that this approach can be naturally extended to any object by implementing your own hash function as a special case in handle_item. For example, to make this approach work for a function that takes a set as an input argument, you could add to handle_item:

```
if is_instance(x, set):
    return make_tuple(sorted(list(x)))
```

Comment: Nice attempt. Without whining, a `list` argument of `[1, 2, 3]` can mistakenly be considered the same as a different `set` argument with a value of `{1, 2, 3}`. In addition, sets are unordered like dictionaries, so they would also need to be `sorted()`. Also note that a recursive data structure argument would cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Yea, sets should be handled by special casing handle_item(x) and sorting. I shouldn't have said that this implementation handles sets, because it doesn't - but the point is that it can be easily extended to do so by special casing handle_item, and the same will work for any class or iterable object as long as you're willing to write the hash function yourself. The tricky part - dealing with multi-dimensional lists or dictionaries - is already dealt with here, so I've found that this memoize function is a lot easier to work with as a base than the simple "I only take hashable arguments" types.

Comment: The problem I mentioned is due to the fact that `list`s and `set`s are "tupleized" into the same thing and therefore become indistinguishable from one another. The example code for adding support for `sets` described in your latest update doesn't avoid that I'm afraid. This can easily be seen by separately passing `[1,2,3]` and `{1,2,3}` as an argument to a "memoize"d test function and seeing whether it's called twice, as it should be, or not.

Comment: yea, I read that problem, but I didn't address it because I think it is much more minor than the other one you mentioned. When was the last time you wrote a memoized function where a fixed argument could be either a list or a set, and the two resulted in different outputs? If you were to run into such a rare case, you would again just rewrite handle_item to prepend, say a 0 if the element is a set, or a 1 if it is a list.

Comment: Actually, there's a similar issue with `list`s and `dict`s because it's _possible_ for a `list` to have exactly the same thing in it that resulted from calling `make_tuple(sorted(x.items()))` for a dictionary. A simple solution for both cases would be to include the `type()` of value in the tuple generated. I can think of an even simpler way specifically to handle `set`s, but it doesn't generalize.

Answer (score 3):

Solution that works with both positional and keyword arguments independently of order in which keyword args were passed (using [inspect.getargspec](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec)):

```
import inspect
import functools

def memoize(fn):
    cache = fn.cache = {}
    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def memoizer(*args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.update(dict(zip(inspect.getargspec(fn).args, args)))
        key = tuple(kwargs.get(k, None) for k in inspect.getargspec(fn).args)
        if key not in cache:
            cache[key] = fn(**kwargs)
        return cache[key]
    return memoizer
```

Similar question: [Identifying equivalent varargs function calls for memoization in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621838/identifying-equivalent-varargs-function-calls-for-memoization-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to add to the answers already provided, the [Python decorator library](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize) has some simple yet useful implementations that can also memoize "unhashable types", unlike `functools.lru_cache`.

Comment: This decorator does not *memoize "unhashable types"*! It just falls back to calling the function without memoization, going against against the *explicit is better than implicit* dogma.

Answer (score 2):

```
cache = {}
def fib(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    else:
        if n not in cache:
            cache[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
        return cache[n]
```

Answer (score 1):

If speed is a consideration:

- `@functools.cache` and `@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)` are equally fast, taking 0.122 seconds (best of 15 runs) to loop a million times on my system
- a global cache variable is quite a lot slower, taking 0.180 seconds (best of 15 runs) to loop a million times on my system
- a `self.cache` class variable is a bit slower still, taking 0.214 seconds (best of 15 runs) to loop a million times on my system

The latter two are implemented similar to how it is described in the [currently top-voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1988826/1201863).

This is without memory exhaustion prevention, i.e. I did not add code in the `class` or `global` methods to limit that cache's size, this is really the barebones implementation. The `lru_cache` method has that for free, if you need this.

One open question for me would be how to unit test something that has a `functools` decorator. Is it possible to empty the cache somehow? Unit tests seem like they would be cleanest using the class method (where you can instantiate a new class for each test) or, secondarily, the global variable method (since you can do `yourimportedmodule.cachevariable = {}` to empty it).

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache `cache_clear()`