# Large runtime difference between two solutions: Project Euler #14

Tags: python, performance

I solved [Project Euler #14](http://projecteuler.net/problem=14) using the following code:

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
def collatz_problem(n):
    count = 0
    while n!=1:
        if n%2==0:
            n = n/2
            count = count+1
        elif n%2!=0:
            n = 3*n+1
            count = count +1
    return count+1


def longest_chain():
    max_len,num = 1,1
    for i in xrange(13,1000000):
        chain_length = collatz_problem(i)
        if chain_length > max_len:
            max_len = chain_length
            num = i

    return num

print longest_chain()
print time.time() - start_time, "seconds"
```

The above solution took around `~35 seconds` to run. Now, I tried another solution from [here](http://www.s-anand.net/euler.html).

Solution:

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
cache = { 1: 1 }
def chain(cache, n):
     if not cache.get(n,0):
         if n % 2: cache[n] = 1 + chain(cache, 3*n + 1)
         else: cache[n] = 1 + chain(cache, n/2)
     return cache[n]
m,n = 0,0
for i in xrange(1, 1000000):
    c = chain(cache, i)
    if c > m: m,n = c,i

print n
print time.time() - start_time, "seconds"
```

Now, this solution only took `~3.5 seconds`.

**First Question:**

Now, as I am a python beginner I cannot see why there is so much of a difference in these two approaches and how can I modify my code to make it more effecient.

**Second Question:**

While solving project euler questions is there any time constraints one should keep in mind and is my code really that ineffecient.

Comment: If you have two questions, ask them as separate questions.

Comment: The same program take me 62 secondes lol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first version you may calculate the length of some chains several times because they are subchains in other chains.

In the second solution you are only calculating the length of each chain once because of the caching. This optimization technique is called [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).

---

A more dramatic example of memoization is calculation of the [Fibonacci numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number). Here's the simple recursive solution:

```
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    else:
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

It takes exponential time because `fib(n)` evaluates `fib(n-1)` and `fib(n-2)`, but `fib(n-1)` also evaluates `fib(n-2)`, so you end up doing the exact same calculation again. Try calculating `fib(35)` or higher with this algorithm.

By caching the results of `fib(x)` for each `x` you can avoid recalculating the same result, improving the performance to linear time.

```
def fib2(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    elif n in cache:
        return cache[n]
    else:
        result = fib2(n-1) + fib2(n-2)
        cache[n] = result
        return result
```

**Related**

- [What is memoization and how can I use it in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988804/what-is-memoization-and-how-can-i-use-it-in-python)

Comment: Mmm.. you've already posted an example... do you want a different example? I can show Fibonacci with memoization.