# Memoization when arguments can be very large

Tags: python, design-patterns, python-3.x, memoization

Let's say I have a referentially transparent function. It is very easy to memoize it; [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1988826/336527):

```
def memoize(obj):
  memo = {}
  @functools.wraps(obj)
  def memoizer(*args, **kwargs):
    combined_args = args + (kwd_mark,) + tuple(sorted(kwargs.items()))
    if combined_args not in memo:
      memo[combined_args] = obj(*args, **kwargs)
    return cache[combined_args]
  return memoizer

@memoize
def my_function(data, alpha, beta):
  # ...
```

Now suppose that the `data` argument to `my_function` is huge; say, it's a `frozenset` with millions of elements. In this case, the cost of memoization is prohibitive: every time, we'd have to calculate `hash(data)` as part of the dictionary lookup.

I can make the `memo` dictionary an attribute to `data` instead of an object inside `memoize` decorator. This way I can skip the `data` argument entirely when doing the cache lookup since the chance that another huge `frozenset` will be the same is negligible. However, this approach ends up polluting an argument passed to `my_function`. Worse, if I have two or more large arguments, this won't help at all (I can only attach `memo` to one argument).

Is there anything else that can be done?

Comment: When you define `my_function`, do you know that you always want to skip memoization of `data`?

Comment: I don't want to skip it. But if I make the `memo` object an attribute of the `data` parameter passed to me, I don't need to include it in the key any longer: after all, by construction a separate `memo` will be used for each `data` object!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use "hash" there with no fears. A frozenset's hash is not calculated more than once by Python - just when it is created - check the timings:

```
>>> timeit("frozenset(a)", "a=range(100)")
3.26825213432312
>>> timeit("hash(a)", "a=frozenset(range(100))")
0.08160710334777832
>>> timeit("(lambda x:x)(a)", "a=hash(frozenset(range(100)))")
0.1994171142578125
```

Don't forget Python's "hash" builtin calls the object's `__hash__` method, which has its return value defined at creation time  for built-in hasheable objects. Above you can see that calling a identity lambda function is more than twice slower than calling "hash (a)"

So, if all your arguments are hasheable, just add their hash when creating "combined_args" - else, just write its creation so that you use hash for frozenset (and maybe other) types, with a conditional.

Comment: While the hash value is indeed not calculated more than once, it is not calculated during creation. And for a large object it's nearly as expensive as the object creation. But I agree, `hash` is not the problem. It seems `__eq__` is a much bigger problem.

Comment: The performance impact is only visible when you try `frozenset(range(100000000))` or something like that.

Comment: Hmm if hash value is not calculated more than once, how come python's own `lru_cache` implementation [created a special class](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/da152dadf5384e47063630bc54bb664899ffa988/Lib/functools.py#L347-L352) just for the purpose of caching the hash value of tuples?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the built-in `__hash__` is not that bad, since it caches its own value after the first calculation. The real performance hit comes from the built-in `__eq__`, since it doesn't short-circuit on identical objects, and actually goes through the full comparison every time, making it very costly.

One approach I thought of is to subclass the built-in class for all large arguments:

```
class MyFrozenSet(frozenset):
  __eq__ = lambda self, other : id(self) == id(other)
  __hash__ = lambda self : id(self)
```

This way, dictionary lookup would be instantaneous. But the equality for the new class will be broken.

A better solution is probably this: only when the dictionary lookup is performed, the large arguments can be wrapped inside a special class that redefines `__eq__` and `__hash__` to be return the wrapped object's `id()`. The obvious implementation of the wrapper is a bit annoying, since it requires copying all the standard `frozenset` methods. Perhaps deriving it from the relevant `ABC` class may make it easier.

Comment: Why not just store the argument's hash?

Comment: Because then you have to be absolutely sure that you won't end up with two different objects with the same hash. I agree the chances of this are nearly negligible, but it is strictly speaking unsafe.

Comment: Don't subclass, *wrap*. Subclassing should (to first approximation) obey the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), and your version certainly doesn't. Even in cases where it does hold, wrapping with a shared API is often better. Also, use `def __hash__(self): return hash(id(self.value))`: that extra `hash` is important for distribution.

Comment: @Veedrac with wrapped approach, which methods would I need to define in the wrapper class?

Comment: @max `__eq__` and `__hash__`.

Comment: @Veedrac I think you're right, I'm not sure why I thought I'd need to copy any other methods, if the only way the wrapped objects are used is to be stored and looked up in the memoization dictionary.