# Comparison of collections containing non-reflexive elements

Tags: python

In python, a value `x` is not always constrained to equal itself.  Perhaps the best known example is `NaN`:

```
>>> x = float("NaN")
>>> x == x
False
```

Now consider a list of exactly one item.  We might consider two such lists to be *equal* if and only the items they contained were *equal*.  For example:

```
>>> ["hello"] == ["hello"]
True
```

But this does not appear to be the case with `NaN`:

```
>>> x = float("NaN")
>>> x == x
False
>>> [x] == [x]
True
```

So these lists of items that are "not equal", are "equal".  But only sometimes ... in particular:

- two lists consisting of the same instance of `NaN` are considered equal; while
- two separate lists consisting of different instances of `NaN` are not equal

Observe:

```
>>> x = float("NaN")
>>> [x] == [x]
True
>>> [x] == [float("NaN")]
False
```

This general behaviour also applies to other collection types such as tuples and sets.  Is there a good rationale for this?

Comment: In case you *want* to compare with NaNs being not-equal, you can use NumPy, which considers them that way: `(np.array(a) == np.array(b)).all()` will return False if there are any NaNs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons),

> In enforcing reflexivity of elements, **the comparison of collections assumes that for a collection element x, x == x is always true**. Based on that assumption, element identity is compared first, and element comparison is performed only for distinct elements. This approach yields the same result as a strict element comparison would, if the compared elements are reflexive. For non-reflexive elements, the result is different than for strict element comparison, and may be surprising: The non-reflexive not-a-number values for example result in the following comparison behavior when used in a list:
>
> ```
>  >>> nan = float('NaN')
>  >>> nan is nan
>  True
>  >>> nan == nan
>  False                 <-- the defined non-reflexive behavior of NaN
>  >>> [nan] == [nan]
>  True                  <-- list enforces reflexivity and tests identity first
> ```

Comment: Is there a known rationale for collections to be reflexive, other than convenience (and comparison efficiency perhaps)?

Comment: It might be an accident of history. See [PEP207](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0207/): "The reflexivity rules *are* assumed by Python.  Thus, the interpreter may swap y>x with x<y, y>=x with x<=y, and may swap the arguments of x==y and x!=y." This is a statement of the way things are. It goes on to say, "(Note: Python currently assumes that x==x is always true and x!=x is never true; this should not be assumed.)" which seems to indicate that `list.__eq__` was implemented with the *assumption* that `x!=x` could never be true even though, as it turns out, that should not have been assumed.

Comment: This is interesting ... do you have a view on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38779970/collection-comparison-is-reflexive-yet-does-not-short-circuit-why) at all?