# Speed Up python code (multiple integral calculations)

Tags: python, integration, mpmath

Is there a way to speed up this code:

```
import mpmath as mp
import numpy as np
from time import time as epochTime

def func(E):
    f = lambda theta: mp.sin(theta) * mp.exp(E * (mp.cos(theta**2) + \
                                                  mp.cos(theta)**2))
    return f

start = epochTime()
mp.mp.dps = 15
mp.mp.pretty = True

E = np.linspace(0, 10, 200)
ints = [mp.quadgl(func(e), [0, mp.pi]) for e in E] # Main Job
print ('Took:{:.3}s'.format(epochTime() - start))
```

Comment: Do you really need arbitrary-precision math?

Comment: @Zhenya, in fact I was not aware of this fact. I think not. As long as I have few correct digits after the point it is OK.

Answer (score 4):

Running your code, I timed it to 5.84s

using [`Memoize`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988804/what-is-memoization-and-how-can-i-use-it-in-python) and simplifying expressions:

```
cos = Memoize(mp.cos)
sin = Memoize(mp.sin)

def func(E):
    def f(t):
        cost = cos(t)
        return sin(t) * mp.exp(E * (cos(t*t) + cost*cost))
    return f
```

I got it down to 3.25s first time, and ~2.8s in the next iterations.

(An even better approach might be using [`lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) from the standard library, but I did not try to time it).

If you are running similar code many times, it may be sensible to `Memoize()` both `func` and `f`, so the computations become trivial ( ~0.364s ).

Replacing `mp` with `math` for cos/sin/exp, I got down to ~1.3s, and now memoizing make the performance worse, for some reason (~1.5s, I guess the lookup time became dominant).

Answer (score 2):

In general, you want to avoid calls to transcendent functions like sin, cos, exp, ln as much as possible, especially in a "hot" function like an integrand.

- Replace x**2 by x*x (often x**2 calls a generic=slow exponentiation function)
- use variables for "expensive" intermediate terms which are used more than once
- transform your equation to reduce or eliminate transcendent functions
- special-case for typical parameter values. Integer exponents are a frequent candidate.
- precompute everything that is constant, espc. in parameterized functions

For the particular example you can substitute z=cos(theta). It is dz = -sin(theta)dtheta. Your integrand becomes

```
-exp(E*(z^2 + cos(arccos(z)^2))
```

saving you some of the transcendent function calls. The boundaries [0, pi] become [1, -1]. Also avoid x**2, better use x*x.

Complete code:

```
import mpmath as mp
import numpy as np
from time import time as epochTime

def func(E):
    def f(z):
        acz = mp.acos(z)
        return -mp.exp(E * (mp.cos(acz*acz) + z*z))
    return f

start = epochTime()
mp.mp.dps = 15
mp.mp.pretty = True

E = np.linspace(0, 10, 200)
ints = [mp.quadgl(func(e), [1.0, -1.0]) for e in E] # Main Job
print ('Took:{:.3}s'.format(epochTime() - start))
```

Comment: The intention was not to change the integrated function. Thanks anyway !

Comment: @rowman but it seems like the best way to improve performance.

Comment: @Elazar, that's true. But this function was just an example. In the real code it would be different from this.

Comment: OK, thought you needed exactly this function. However the generic ideas can be applied to lots of such problems.