# Fast Numerical Integration in Python

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-methods

I have a program that involves computing a definite integral many times, and have been struggling to find a way to do so quickly.  The integrals I need to solve are of the following form:

[image: \int^{b}_{a(r)}f(x)*g(x-r)dx]

I have to solve this integral for many different values of r, which affects both the limits of integration and also the integrand (through the function g). Because of this, I have not found a way to vectorize the problem and must instead rely on loops.  This significantly slows down the problem, because I need to make function calls in each loop.  Below is one way to do it using loops (using made up data and functions):

```
import numpy as np 

f = lambda x: x**2
g = lambda x: np.log(x)

b=1000
r = np.arange(10,500,10)
a = 1.1*r+r**-1

def loop1(r,a):
    integration_range=[np.linspace(a[i],b,1000) for i in range(len(a))]
    out=np.zeros(len(r))
    i=0
    while i<len(r):
        out[i]=np.trapz(f(integration_range[i])*a_pdf(integration_range[i]-r[i]),integration_range[i])
        i=i+1
    return out
```

This takes approximately 17.7 ms, which is too slow for my current needs. I don't care too much about getting the integrals to be super precise; I would be happy with a solution that gave approximations within 1% of the true value. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried scipy? They offer all kinds of integration techniques
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html

Comment: I have, but those methods are also too slow

Comment: [Ctypes will speed it up](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html#faster-integration-using-ctypes) or try [using the GPU](https://developer.nvidia.com/how-to-cuda-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have lot's of these to do and f is more complicated than your example, you could get some benefits from memoizing f and possibly g.

[What is memoization and how can I use it in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988804/what-is-memoization-and-how-can-i-use-it-in-python)

Basically, anywhere you can, cache a computation and trade memory for cpu.