# Order of operations and fast computation in Python

Tags: python, performance, optimization

I am trying to optimize a Python code where the following mathematical function has to be evaluated many (many) times

```
from math import pow, pi
from scipy.special import gamma

def norm_spirals(a,k):
    return pi*pow(abs(gamma(0.25+0.5*k+0.5j*a)/gamma(0.75+0.5*k+0.5j*a)),2)
```

I have already optimized as much as possible my code using `cProfile` and `timeit`. I also got rid of the `call` to the procedure and direcly embedded this calculation in the code. The last step of optimization I could think of, is to tune the order of the mathematical operations in order to accelerate the evaluation. The formula above is the fastest form that I have been able to obtain using `timeit`.

- Would you think of another order of calculation for this formula that could be faster ?
- Would you have any ideas of other optimizations I could use ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: the next level would be to see how this function is called - i.e. in a for loop, in a list comprehension, in an inefficient while/next structure, etc. but sounds like you have already done that.

Comment: @CorleyBrigman This function is basically an integrand function called via `scipy.integrate.quad`. That's why it is evaluated so many times...

Comment: what kind of values do a and k take? might it be possible to store the results of this or gamma in some table (I note that the two calls to gamma are basically a difference of 1 in k), or are they different all the time?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich `k` is an integer (positive or negative), whereas `a` is a float (on which I will integrate). The difference between the two arguments of the `gamma` function is exactly 1/2, so that there is no straigthforward mathematical simplification ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)). I had thought of storing a table of the values of `norm_spirals`, but the problem is that I can't predict where the adaptative algorithm of `scipy.integrate.quad` will ask me to evaluate the function...

Comment: You may be sure that code is your only bottleneck, but if I were you, I would just spend a little effort to prove it with [*this technique*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4299378/23771). Also, you are calling `pow(...,2)` and relying on it to be smart enough not to call `log` and `exp`. I wouldn't take that chance - I would just put `...` in a local and square it myself.

Comment: "there is no straigthforward mathematical simplification": on the opposite, the duplication formula will allow you to trade two calls to gamma for one. And instead of squaring abs, you could evaluate Re^2+Im^2 to avoid squaring a square root.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Unfortunately, the duplication formula look like `gamma(z) gamma(z+1/2) ~ gamma(2z)`. But in my case, I have to study a term of the form `gamma(z)/gamma(z+1/2)`, so that I always have to deal with two calls to gamma... However, if you find out any faster evaluation of this term, you're more than welcome !

Comment: Ooops, yes, I didn't see the '/' :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are four simple transformations to speed-up your code:

1) Replace `pow(x, 2)` with `x ** 2.0`:

```
def norm_spirals(a,k):
    return pi* abs(gamma(0.25+0.5*k+0.5j*a)/gamma(0.75+0.5*k+0.5j*a)) ** 2.0
```

2)  Factor-out the [common subexpression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination): `0.25+0.5*k+0.5j*a`

```
def norm_spirals(a,k):
    se = 0.25 + 0.5*k + 0.5j*a
    return pi * abs(gamma(se)/gamma(se + 0.5)) ** 2.0
```

3)  Localize the global lookups:

```
def norm_spirals(a,k, pi=pi, abs=abs, gamma=gamma):
    se = 0.25 +0.5*k + 0.5j*a
    return pi * abs(gamma(se)/gamma(se + 0.5)) ** 2.0
```

4)  Replace the square operation with `b * b`.  This is called [strength reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strength_reduction):

```
def norm_spirals(a,k, pi=pi, abs=abs, gamma=gamma):
    se = 0.25 + 0.5*k + 0.5j * a
    b = abs(gamma(se)/gamma(se + 0.5))
    return b * b * pi
```

Comment: Is not `value*value` also faster than `value**2` as well?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I've modified the answer accordingly.  Thank you.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger I used your rewritting and also directly embedded this calculation in the code, so that this procedure is no more called. It sped up the calculation by about 20%, which is definitely non-negligible.

Answer (score 0):

I get it 15% faster (python 2.7) by introducing a temp var and remove the call to pow:

```
def norm_spirals(a, k):
    _ = 0.5 * k + 0.5j * a
    return pi * abs(gamma(0.25 + _) / gamma(0.75 + _)) ** 2
```

For python 3 the gain was just 11%.

*Disclaimer:*
I didn't have scipy installed so for gamma I used

```
def gamma(a):
    return a
```

So "15% faster" might be a bit misleading.

Answer (score 0):

If `norm_spirals()` is invoked many times with the same arguments, then you can try [memoization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988804/what-is-memoization-and-how-can-i-use-it-in-python) to cache the results and see if it makes a difference.