# Regex taking too long during loop

Tags: python, regex

This is the simple version of my code.

```
    for i in range(len(holdList)):
        foundTerm = re.findall(r"\b" + self._searchTerm +
            r"\b", holdList[i][5], flags=re.IGNORECASE)
        # count the occurrence
        storyLen = len(foundTerm)
        holdList[i] += (storyLen,)
        if foundTerm:
            # Stores each found word as a list of strings
            # etc
            holdList[i] += (self.sentences_to_quote(holdList[i][5]), )
```

During the loop(the last line) I call upon a different method to look through each sentence and it returns that sentence that has the word. The holdList is a tuple from a MySQL query.

```
def sentences_to_quote(self, chapter):
    """
    Seperates the chapter into sentences
    Returns the first occurrence of the word in the sentence
    """

    # Seperate the chapters into sentences
    searchSentences = sent_tokenize.tokenize(chapter, realign_boundaries=True)
    findIt = r"\b" + self._searchTerm + r"\b"
    for word in searchSentences:
        regex = (re.sub(findIt,  
            "**" + self._searchTerm.upper() + "**", 
            word, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
        if regex != word:
            return regex
```

What can I do to speed this up? Is there anything I can do? The program is going through 10MB of text. Through profiling I found these two areas to be the bottleneck. I hope I provided enough info to make it clear.

Comment: is tokenization fast and/or each row in `holdList` contains different chapter? if it's slow and you do it for the same chapter over and over, have a look at [memoization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988804/what-is-memoization-and-how-can-i-use-it-in-python) techniques..

Comment: This is too vague, your performance problems could be in using `+` for string concatenation, using uncompiled regular expressions, for using too many attribute lookups (`.`) in a loop and so on... How did you profile this and how exactly do you know that its the regexp that is slow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether your `self._searchTerm` will consist of phrases or words but in general you will get much better results from using `set`s and `dict`s rather than regex. You don't need the regex machinery in this case since all you want is to count/match complete words. To search for a certain word in a sentence, for example, you can easily replace this by:

```
search_sentence = set(sent_tokenize.tokenize(...))
if self._search_term in search_sentence:
    # yay
```

(I made your code PEP8 compliant.)

If you're worried about capitalization then convert everything to lower case:

```
self._search_term = self._search_term.lower()
search_sentence = set(word.lower() for word in sent_tokenize.tokenize(...))
if self._search_term in search_sentence:
    # yay
```

You can also count occurrences of words using a `collection.Counter` or `collection.defaultdict(int)`.

If you must use regex because you want to match words that follow a specific pattern rather than matching entire words then I suggest you compile the pattern once and then pass that pattern to the other methods, e.g.,

```
self.search_pattern = re.compile(r"\b{term}\b".format(term=self._search_term), re.I)
found_term = self.search_pattern.find_all(hold_list[i][5])
```

Comment: +1 for replacing `re.sub` by `in` set operator, note this might be faster - `search_sentence = set(sent_tokenize.tokenize(capter.lower(), ...))`

Comment: Ah thank you for the obvious on how question I wondered on how to re.compile before assignment. Will setS and dictS work though if the searchTerm is a phrase? Searches are not limited in char size or word amount.

Comment: Sets and dictionaries work for phrases too, since any string can be a dictionary key or set element, it's just not as straightforward to search for them. If you are searching for a three-word phrase, for example, you might have to build your set from overlapping three-word phrases in order to check whether the set contains the search phrase. There are probably smarter ways to do that sort of search.

Answer (score 1):

re.sub is used to replace the string if it matches the regex.
your task here is only to find if a match exists, hence instead using re.search would give
you a performance boost, re.search gives you the first match.

Comment: I see, would it be that noticeable though? Right now I currently do that so the returned sentenced would have the word bolded but of course if it's a big difference then it's worth it.

Comment: Sorry, stupid of me to ask. The performance was the same though.