# Assigning and Referencing Data Given By Function

Tags: python, performance

I think this is actually a simple question for comp. sci. people, but I am not in a comp. sci. program and can't remember any terminology.

I have made a large set of functions which are essentially nested to create a large numpy record array.

```
data = func_to_make_large_structure()
```

Now, when I assign `data` like this, does it store the large structure as it is after the function returns, or does the function get called and re-calculate every time it is called?
It is taking 30 seconds to make the structure, which is considerably longer than it takes  for a similar structure to be created in OO by using an object to store the data.
In addition, I then do a large amount of processing on the data which takes much longer for the functional program than the OO form.

Is this because the data is being recalculated every time the `data` is called?
If so, how do I store just the data without calling the function everytime?

Comment: It would probably be useful to tag this with the language you are using

Comment: Usually in these cases, referencing `data` after this line will not invoke another call to `func_to_make_large_structure()` because you are assigning the *result* of that function into `data`.
HOWEVER, some languages allow you to pass back function pointers or function references. If that's the case, then you may be invoking a function call every time you reference `data`. So, as said above, it would be really helpful to know
1) your language
2) what the declaration of `func_to_make_large_structure()` looks like (what are the parameters and return types?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the function is called, the variable `data` no longer has any association with the function, so if you call `func_to_make_large_structure()` again, it will do all the same calculations again. A technique to avoid this is called [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) and techniques for using it in Python are described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988804/what-is-memoization-and-how-can-i-use-it-in-python).

But if you're asking if after the initial call, `func_to_make_large_structure` is called each time the `data` variable is accessed, then no.