# Reduce a string using grammar-like rules

Tags: string, algorithm, language-agnostic, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to find a suitable DP algorithm for simplifying a string. For example I have a string `a b a b` and a list of rules

1. `a b -> b`
2. `a b -> c`
3. `b a -> a`
4. `c c -> b`

The purpose is to get all single chars that can be received from the given string using these rules. For this example it will be `b, c`. The length of the given string can be up to 200 symbols. Could you please prompt an effective algorithm?

Rules always are `2 -> 1`. I've got an idea of creating a tree, root is given string and each child is a string after one transform, but I'm not sure if it's the best way.

Comment: does the rule always have 2 to 1 maping? what is your best solution ? the shortest string? the string with most same letters?

Comment: You need to show us some effort. Have you considered how you would approach this problem? Give us your thoughts. *Try something.* When you get stuck, post showing us what you've tried and explain what the problem is.

Comment: And what do you mean with [DP](http://www.acronymfinder.com/Information-Technology/DP.html)?

Comment: @Bas probably dynamic programming

Comment: @Dialecticus I thought so, but I hate to be guessing. There is even a [tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-programming) for that ...

Comment: @Bas DP is dynamic programming. Sorry for mistake, I've already added the tag.

Comment: @cerkiewny yes, the rule is always 2 to 1. There is no best solution, purpose is to get all possible solutions.

Comment: Why is `a b -> ..` twice in your list? Also: is every output character written directly, i.e., not processed anymore, or do you keep it as the next 'first' character and restart at the top?

Comment: @Jongware 'a b' can be transformed to 'b' or to 'c', so there are two rules. I'm not sure I've understood your second question right, but it doesn't matter if 'b' can be received in 2 different ways, only thing that matters is that it can be received.

Comment: In your example `a b a b`, the first transformation is Rule 1: `a b -> b` (or Rule 2: `a b - > c` - but how would you know which one to use?). Does that lead to the new string `b a b` ( and use Rule 3) or is `b` immediately "consumed", leaving `a b` as next input (and use Rule 1 again)?

Comment: @Jongware Using Rule 1 on first letters of `a b a b` leads to string `b a b`

Comment: Wouldn't CKY work for this essentially unmodified?

Answer (score 2):

For a DP problem, you always need to understand how you can construct the answer for a big problem in terms of smaller sub-problems. Assume you have your function `simplify` which is called with an input of length `n`. There are `n-1` ways to split the input in a first and a last part. For each of these splits, you should recursively call your `simplify` function on both the first part and the last part. The final answer for the input of length `n` is the set of all possible combinations of answers for the first and for the last part, which are allowed by the rules.

In Python, this can be implemented like so:

```
rules = {'ab': set('bc'), 'ba': set('a'), 'cc': set('b')}
all_chars = set(c for cc in rules.values() for c in cc)

@ memoize
def simplify(s):
    if len(s) == 1:  # base case to end recursion
        return set(s)

    possible_chars = set()

    # iterate over all the possible splits of s
    for i in range(1, len(s)):
        head = s[:i]
        tail = s[i:]

        # check all possible combinations of answers of sub-problems
        for c1 in simplify(head):
            for c2 in simplify(tail):
                possible_chars.update(rules.get(c1+c2, set()))

                # speed hack
                if possible_chars == all_chars: #  won't get any bigger
                    return all_chars

    return possible_chars
```

Quick check:

```
In [53]: simplify('abab')
Out[53]: {'b', 'c'}
```

To make this fast enough for large strings (to avoiding exponential behavior), you should use a [memoize decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988804/what-is-memoization-and-how-can-i-use-it-in-python). This is a critical step in solving DP problems, otherwise you are just doing a brute-force calculation. A further tiny speedup can be obtained by returning from the function as soon as `possible_chars == set('abc')`, since at that point, you are already sure that you can generate all possible outcomes.

Analysis of running time: for an input of length `n`, there are 2 substrings of length `n-1`, 3 substrings of length `n-2`, ... n substrings of length 1, for a total of `O(n^2)` subproblems. Due to the memoization, the function is called at most once for every subproblem. Maximum running time for a single sub-problem is `O(n)` due to the `for i in range(len(s))`, so the overall running time is at most `O(n^3)`.

Comment: I'm not good at Python and have several questions. Does `head = s[:i]; tail = s[i:]` split string in two parts on index i or take i char's from both ends of the string? And what makes `possible_chars.update(rules.get(c1+c2, set()))`?

Comment: 1) that is slice notation, `s[:i] == s[0:i]`, which corresponds to the first `i` characters, and `s[i:] == s[i:len(s)]` takes all but the first `i` characters. So for an input `abcd`, the loop over `i` would split this into `head, tail = 'a','bcd'`, `head, tail = 'ab', 'cd'` and `head, tail = 'abc', 'd'`.

Comment: 2) That is a compact way for: concatenate chars `c1` and `c2`, look up the possible set of answers for this combination in the rules dictionary, and finally make `possible_chars` the [union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28set_theory%29) of itself and possible set of answers from the rules. The `get(key, default)` method on a dictionary looks up a key in a dictionary, and if it is not found returns a default value. I use this to return an empty set `set()` in case the 2-letter combination is not in the rules, so the union with that does nothing.

Comment: A more explicit way would be to write `if c1+c2 in rules: possible_chars = possible_chars.union(rules[c1+c2])`.

Comment: For the completeness of the code I think it's good to add a definition of `memoize`. Or it's taken from some Python library that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2):

If you read those rules from right to left, they look exactly like the rules of a context free grammar, and have basically the same meaning. You could apply a bottom-up parsing algorithm like the [Earley algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earley_parser) to your data, along with a suitable starting rule; something like

```
start <- start a
       | start b
       | start c
```

and then just examine the parse forest for the shortest chain of `start`s. The worst case remains O(n^3) of course, but Earley is fairly effective, these days.

You can also produce parse forests when [parsing with derivatives](http://matt.might.net/papers/might2011derivatives.pdf). You might be able to efficiently check them for short chains of `start`s.

Answer (score 1):

Let N - length of given string and R - number of rules.

Expanding a tree in a top down manner yields computational complexity O(NR^N) in the worst case (input string of type `aaa...` and rules `aa -> a`).

Proof:

Root of the tree has (N-1)R children, which have (N-1)R^2 children, ..., which have (N-1)R^N children (leafs). So, the total complexity is O((N-1)R + (N-1)R^2 + ... (N-1)R^N) = O(N(1 + R^2 + ... + R^N)) = (using [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)) = O(N(R+1)^N) = O(NR^N).

Recursive Java implementation of this naive approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Character[]> rules = new HashMap<String, Character[]>() {{
        put("ab", new Character[]{'b', 'c'});
        put("ba", new Character[]{'a'});
        put("cc", new Character[]{'b'});
    }};
    System.out.println(simplify("abab", rules));
}

public static Set<String> simplify(String in, Map<String, Character[]> rules) {
    Set<String> result = new HashSet<String>();
    simplify(in, rules, result);
    return result;
}

private static void simplify(String in, Map<String, Character[]> rules, Set<String> result) {
    if (in.length() == 1) {
        result.add(in);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < in.length() - 1; i++) {
        String two = in.substring(i, i + 2);
        Character[] rep = rules.get(two);
        if (rep != null) {
            for (Character c : rep) {
                simplify(in.substring(0, i) + c + in.substring(i + 2, in.length()), rules, result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

[Bas Swinckels's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132361/reduce-a-string-using-grammar-like-rules#answer-30133669) O(RN^3) Java implementation (with `HashMap` as a memoization cache):

```
public static Set<String> simplify2(final String in, Map<String, Character[]> rules) {
    Map<String, Set<String>> cache = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
    return simplify2(in, rules, cache);
}

private static Set<String> simplify2(final String in, Map<String, Character[]> rules, Map<String, Set<String>> cache) {
    final Set<String> cached = cache.get(in);
    if (cached != null) {
        return cached;
    }
    Set<String> ret = new HashSet<String>();
    if (in.length() == 1) {
        ret.add(in);
        return ret;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < in.length(); i++) {
        String head = in.substring(0, i);
        String tail = in.substring(i, in.length());
        for (String c1 : simplify2(head, rules)) {
            for (String c2 : simplify2(tail, rules, cache)) {
                Character[] rep = rules.get(c1 + c2);
                if (rep != null) {
                    for (Character c : rep) {
                        ret.add(c.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cache.put(in, ret);
    return ret;
}
```

---

Output in both approaches:

```
[b, c]
```

Comment: I am not very fluent in Java, but does your second implementation use memoization (i.e. caching the result for fixed inputs)? If not, it is not `O(n^3)`, but exponential.

Comment: Thank you, both algorithms work perfectly, but I need a little help with optimization. The second algorithm is fast, but I need it to be a little faster. May be you could give me some advice on optimization, for example use a faster data structure or more effective loop?

Comment: @user2875945 I didn't implement Bas Swinckels "speed hack" (look at his code), this should help with performance.