# Django custom tags reusablity

Tags: python, django

I have a simple custom tag that will return a list of objects

```
@register.simple_tag
def get_languages(obj):
    return obj.get_languages()
```

is there a way such that in my templates, i can save the result of the custom tag so that i can reuse it else where in my html?

```
{% get_languages project as used_languages %}
<span class="tag">{{ used_languages.0.name }}</span>
<span class="tag">{{ used_languages.1.name }}</span>
<span class="tag">{{ used_languages.2.name }}</span>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want `obj.get_languages()` to be called only the first time the tag is used and for subsequent calls to use a stored result?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to memoize your tag:

```
get_languages_cache = None

@register.simple_tag
def get_languages(obj):
    if get_languages_cache is None:
        get_languages_cache = obj.get_languages()
    return get_languages_cache
```

This assumes `obj.get_languages()` never returns `None`. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988804/what-is-memoization-and-how-can-i-use-it-in-python) for further discussion and examples of memoization in Python.