# confused about python decorators. When/how are they called?

Tags: python, decorator

Can someone explain the code snippet below? I'm a bit confused by the syntax `@memoize`. When/how is it called? What does it do?

```
import functools

def memoize(fn):
    known = dict()

    @functools.wraps(fn)
    def memoizer(*args):
        if args not in known:
            known[args] = fn(*args)
        return known[args]

    return memoizer

@memoize
def fibonacci(n):
    '''Returns the nth number of the Fibonacci sequence'''
    assert(n >= 0), 'n must be >= 0'
    return n if n in (0, 1) else fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(fibonacci(10))
```

Comment: it's called during code load. it's the same as having: 

def fibonacci(n):
    # etc
    pass

fibonacci = memoize(fibonacci)

Comment: Are you confused about decorators in general or the memoization one? I'm asking because you're basically asking, "What does this code do?" Which is too broad. There are a lot of resources online explaining decorators, and [here is](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1988804/2615940) a SO question about memoization.

Comment: ``memoize`` caches the values of the fibonacci computation. if the values were computed before, it returns them from the dict ``known`` and doesn't recompute them.

Comment: I was pretty much confused about when and how the function `memoize` is getting called. I read the decorators docs a bunch of times, but the language isn't extremely clear (at least not to me).

Comment: @AlexDicianu by decorating `fibonacci` with `@memoize` you are actually binding the fibonacci name/variable to the function returned by `memoize(fibonacci)`. So `memoizer` is "implicitly" called every time you call `fibonacci`, while `memoize` is called one time when defining `fibonacci`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@memoize
def fibonacci(n):
    ...
```

Is the same thing as

```
def fibonacci(n):
    ...

fibonacci = memoize(fibonacci)
```

See [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/how-can-i-make-a-chain-of-function-decorators-in-python/1594484#1594484) for a detailed explanation on how decorators work.

Comment: `fibonacci = memoize(fibonacci)`, without the argument

Comment: Thanks LeartS, I've updated my answer.