# How to save value returned from python function if call does not capture return

Tags: python

Let's say I have a python function, where `x` and `y` are relatively large objects (lists, NumPy matrices, etc.):

```
def myfun(x):
  y=some complicated function of x
  return y
```

If in an interactive session the user calls this as:

```
myfun(5)
```

The call is basically useless, since `y` is lost. Let's also suppose the function takes a while to run. Is there a way to retrieve the answer, so the user doesn't have to re-run, i.e. `answer=myfun(5)`? Alternatively, what is a good (pythonic) way to write the function to make it 'fool-proof' for this scenario? Some not-so-great options are:

Require a parameter that stores the value, e.g.

```
def myfun(x,y):
  y = some complicated function of x
  return y
```

Or maybe:

```
def myfun(x):
  y = some complicated function of x
  global temp
  temp = y
  return y
```

In the latter case, if a user then mistakenly called `myfun(5)`, there's the option of `y=temp` to get the answer back.. but using `global` just seems wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988804/what-is-memoization-and-how-can-i-use-it-in-python

Comment: @danidee good related answer (although probably overkill for this particular question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`y=_`

assuming you are in the interactive python console. `_` is magic that holds the last "result"

Comment: (additionally the question does not make much sense outside of that context :P )

Comment: And if you're using IPython, results like this are also stored in the `Out` object, so you can look at the little `Out[15]:` or `Out[42]:` label next to your output and access `Out[15]` or `Out[42]` to get at objects that have been shoved out of `_` by further outputs.

Comment: ahh I fiigured ipython had some extra bells and whistles :P but i dont use it enough so :P

Comment: Wow, that was a perfect and easy solution, thank you!