# How to improve time complexity of depicted python program

Tags: performance, python-3.x, optimization

I want to optimize this code but I have no idea how to do further optimization.
Here is an example of the input:

```
3 #size of array  
3 4 3 #data in array  
6 # number of commands  
C 1 2  
C 1 3  
C 3 3  
U 1 4  
C 1 3  
C 1 2
```

'C' and 'U' refer to the following operations:

```
C X Y : Compute the value of F( A[X] ) + F( A[X + 1] ) + F( A[X + 2] ) + .... + F( A[Y] ) (mod 10^9 + 7)
U X Y: Update the element of array A[X] = Y
```

Here is my code:

```
from fractions import gcd
local_gcd=gcd
def F(x):
    global local_gcd
    sum1=0
    for i in range(1,x+1):
         sum1+=local_gcd(i,x)
    return sum1   
size_of_list=int(input())
ele=input()
eles=ele.split(" ")
A=[]
for i in eles:
    A.append(int(i))

num_of_commands=int(input())
mod_val=1000000007
for i in range(0,num_of_commands):
    com=input()
    com_list=com.split(" ")
    x=int(com_list[1])
    y=int(com_list[2])
    sum1=0
    if com_list[0]=='C':
        for i in range(x,y+1):
            sum1+=F(A[i-1])
        print(sum1%mod_val)
    elif com_list[0]=='U':
        A[x-1]=y
```

Answer (score 0):

You can speed it up using [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).  That is, once you figure out what F(i) is, you never need to calculate it again.

In your example, the F() invocations you will make are:

```
F(3), F(4)
F(3), F(4), F(3)
F(3)
F(4), F(4), F(3)
F(4), F(4)
```

By "memoizing" F(), you only need to compute two values: F(3) and F(4).

If you are using Python 3.2 or later, try the built-in `functools.lru_cache` decorator which does this automatically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14731729/4323