# Ensure queryset is cached

Tags: python, django, caching

I am calling a function that starts a process that takes longer to execute, many different things are done. This function chiefly handles instances of a particular class, `Item`. These items are categorized by different attributes: `category1`, `category2` and `category3`.

Now, there is a different model that applies some sort of rules to these categories: `Rule` with many-to-many attributes: `categories1`, `categories2` and `categories3`. A rule applies to an `Item`, if the same rule points to different categories, only one of them should be applied. The decision of which one is defined by a certain logic encapsulated in a function:

```
class Rule(models.Model):
    warehouse = models.ForeignKey('Warehouse')
    categories1 = models.ManyToManyField('Category1')
    categories2 = models.ManyToManyField('Category2')
    categories3 = models.ManyToManyField('Category3')

    @staticmethod
    def get_rules_that_applies(item):
        rules = warehouse.rule_set.all()
        if not rules.exists():
            return None
        # ... determine which rule applies to the item by filtering, etc.
        return rule
```

The issue lies in the `get_rules_that_applies` method. Every time we need to get the rule that applies to a certain item and let me say again that many many items are involved in the process we are talking about, `warehouse.rule_set.all()` is called.

Since the rules **will not** change during this process, we can just cache all the rules in the ware house, but how? How can I make sure `warehouse = warehouse.rule_set.all()` is cached and all filtering and QuerySet operations that act on these rules are not hitting the database?

Comment: What is warehouse in get_rules_that_applies?

Comment: @DimaKudosh yeah I should have mentioned it: the `warehouse` is like the "master/context" object where all the process happens. Everything in the app revolves around a single `warehouse` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the solution you are seeking is the [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) of the `get_rules_that_applies` method.

There is a tool ready-made for that, called [`django-memoize`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-memoize) and [those](https://pythonhosted.org/django-memoize/) are its docs.

Quick-start on usage:

1. `pip install django-memoize`
2. Place it on your `INSTALLED_APPS`

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
       '...',
       'memoize',
   ]
   ```
3. In your `model.py`:

   ```
   from memoize import memoize

   class Rule(models.Model):
       warehouse = models.ForeignKey('Warehouse')
       categories1 = models.ManyToManyField('Category1')
       categories2 = models.ManyToManyField('Category2')
       categories3 = models.ManyToManyField('Category3')

       @staticmethod
       @memoize(timeout=something_reasonable_in_seconds)
       def get_rules_that_applies(item):
           rules = warehouse.rule_set.all()
           if not rules.exists():
               return None
              # ... determine which rule applies to the item by filtering, etc.
           return rules
   ```

---

**(Update) A Semi-DIY Approach:**

Since my answer, I read the following post: https://www.peterbe.com/plog/cache_memoize-cache-decorator-for-django which is accompanied by a [gist](https://gist.github.com/peterbe/fd6ffc23325df849b27c549e769ce570) on how to achieve memoization yourself.

---

**A More DIY Approach:**

**Python 3.2 and up:**

The [`@functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) decorator which is a:

> Decorator to wrap a function with a memoizing callable that saves up to the maxsize most recent calls. It can save time when an expensive or I/O bound function is periodically called with the same arguments.

How to use it:

```
from functools import lru_cache


class Rule(models.Model):
    ...

    @lru_cache(maxsize=a_reasonable_integer_size_of_cache)
    def get_rules_that_applies(item):
        rules = warehouse.rule_set.all()
        if not rules.exists():
            return None
            # ... determine which rule applies to the item by filtering, etc.
        return rules
```

`maxsize`: Defines the size of the cache in function calls to be stored. It can be set to `None` to cache every call.

**Python < 3.2**

In here [What is memoization and how can I use it in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988804/what-is-memoization-and-how-can-i-use-it-in-python?answertab=votes#tab-top) exist a more "old school" approach.

---

**How to cache a queryset with either of the above methods:**

Why not define an intermediate function to form the queryset and cache that functions results?

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)

or 

@memoize()
def middle_function():
    return warehouse.rule_set.all()
```

and then in your `get_rules_that_applies` function:

```
def get_rules_that_applies(item):
    rules = middle_function()
```

Comment: I'm not really after a cache with a timeout, it can and should be cashed during the entire lifecycle of the execution of the process (you can easily tell when it finishes when the `warehouse` instance is freed up from memory). Also, that would cache the rule for the item right? (since it's caching the function results) Can't I just force-cache a queryset?

Comment: @dabadaba I made an edit on how to cache a queryset as I imagine it :)

Btw, for `memoize` I don't know, but the `lru_cache` doesn't seem to have a timeout.

Comment: I just realized I can't use `django-memoize` because my Django version is older.

Comment: @dabadaba You can still use the `@lru_cache` though or create your own as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988804/what-is-memoization-and-how-can-i-use-it-in-python?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: using Python 2.7 so I guess I can't

Comment: @dabadaba If you cannot upgrade to Python 3.2+ or A greater version of Django, you can create your own `memoize` class as show in the linked so answer (I have edited my answer to include that as well). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 option:

1. cache the item in the view
2. cahce the item in the model

The code will be the same in view and in the model, Import cahce:

```
from django.core.cache import cache
```

Code:

```
if cache.get('query_result') is not None:
    return cache.get('query_result')
else:
    cache.set('query_result', result, 3600)
    #cache.set('cache_name', 'your query', 'expiry time')
    return rule
```

Your model will be:

```
class Rule(models.Model):
warehouse = models.ForeignKey('Warehouse')
categories1 = models.ManyToManyField('Category1')
categories2 = models.ManyToManyField('Category2')
categories3 = models.ManyToManyField('Category3')

@staticmethod
def get_rules_that_applies(item):
    rules = warehouse.rule_set.all()
    if not rules.exists():
        return None
    # ... determine which rule applies to the item by filtering, etc.
    if cache.get('query_result') is not None:
        return cache.get('query_result')
    else:
        cache.set('query_result', result, 3600)
        #cache.set('cache_name', 'your query', 'expiry time')
        return rule

    return rule
```

Few info about Django query, When they are evaluated?:

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated

Hope this help

Comment: this would be caching the rule that applies to the item, not the source queryset of rules