# Assign known values instead of calculating them?

Tags: python

If I am creating a program that does some complex calculations on a data set and I already know what some of the values should be, should I still calculate them? For example if I know that 0 or 1 would always be themselves should I just check if the value is 0 or 1 or actually do the calculations?

#### Edit:

I don't have code because I was asking as a concept. I was creating a program to return the base 10 log of each number in a data set and I was wondering if it would be more efficient to return values I already knew like 0 for 1, "undefined" for 0, and the number of zeros for numbers divisible by 10. I wasn't sure if it was more efficient and if it would be efficient on a larger scale.

Comment: Can you give some example code?

Comment: So, something like this? `return x if x in [0,1] else complex_func(x)`

Comment: You seem to be talking about [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) which is a method of optimization by re-using values that have already been computed.

This has been [discussed here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988804/what-is-memoization-and-how-can-i-use-it-in-python).

Comment: I think that would be an example of premature optimisation. Assuming you are using `math.log`  your testing of special cases in Python is likely to take a relatively long time. Your average case will run longer, since any value that isn't a special case is running extra code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this simple example

```
$ python3 -m timeit -s "from math import log; mylog=lambda x: log(x)" "mylog(1)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.152 usec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit -s "from math import log; mylog=lambda x: 0.0 if x==1 else log(x)" "mylog(1)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0976 usec per loop
```

So there is some speedup, however. All the non special cases run slower

```
$ python3 -m timeit -s "from math import log; mylog=lambda x: log(x)" "mylog(2)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.164 usec per loop
$ python3 -m timeit -s "from math import log; mylog=lambda x: 0.0 if x==1 else log(x)" "mylog(2)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.176 usec per loop
```

And in this case, it's better just to leave the wrapper function out altogether

```
$ python3 -m timeit -s "from math import log" "log(2)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0804 usec per loop
```

Comment: Would this be better when doing bigger calculations? Also, would checking more cases make it more efficient like using the number of 0's when the number is divisible by 10?

Comment: @JoyalMathew, I think it's going to be hard to improve in the case of `log`. In the general case it's often possible to use a list or a dict to store the special/common values. If the computation takes longer than a dict lookup it can definitely be worthwhile. That is basically how  memoization works.