# How can I solve the Multiprocessing.Pool problem?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use multiprocessing as following python codes.

Code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def fibo(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2)

def print_fibo(n): 
    print(fibo(n))

num_list = [31, 32, 33, 34]

pool = Pool(processes=4) 
pool.map(print_fibo, num_list)
```

result:

```
In[1]: runfile('D:/PYTHONcoding/test.py', wdir='D:/PYTHONcoding')
```

This result seems like an infinite loop..

I got 'intel xeon cpu/ 16G RAM/ 1080ti gpu/ etc'.
Please let me know how to use Multiprocess.Pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[blhsing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53182651/1256452) identifies the root of the problem: on Windows, `multiprocessing` requires running a new instance of Python for each computational process.  Each new Python loads the file(s) that define the various functions, then waits for directives from the master / controlling Python that spawned them—but if the Python file(s) that `multiprocessing` loads spawn additional Pythons unconditionally, without an `if __name__ == '__main__'` test, those additional Pythons spawn more Pythons which spawn yet more Pythons, without end.

(Essentially, the problem here is recursion without a base case.)

[Prune's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53182653/1256452), suggesting memoization, is also reasonable.  Note that memoization can be done without global variables.  See [What is memoization and how can I use it in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1988804/1256452) for a prepackaged version.  One I like to use as a demo makes use of the fact that you can set attributes on functions:

```
def fibo(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 0 if n < 1 else 1
    ns = str(n)
    if not hasattr(fibo, ns):
        setattr(fibo, ns, fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2))
    return getattr(fibo, ns)
```

We handle the base cases up front to avoid recursion.  Then we turn the argument `n` (which is presumably a number) into a string `ns` for `getattr` and `setattr`.  If the memoized answer is not available, we set it with a recursive call; then we return the memoized answer.

Comment: Thank you. In this code, adding (if __name__ == '__main__') works well.
I have additional question. 
I want to use the Multiprocessing.Pool inside function (I mean a def..). 
Than, could I just coding like following example? 
>> def function_name(param):
...               if __name__ == '__main__':
...                         pool = Pool(processes = num)
...                         pool.map(another_def, range)

Comment: @HyojeongMoon: It's too hard to read code in comments. If you have a new question, post a new question. (But be sure to search for existing answers first.)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following condition in your main module:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    pool.map(print_fibo, num_list)
```

With this change, you code would output (takes about 5 seconds for me on an average laptop):

```
1346269
2178309
3524578
5702887
```

Answer (score 0):

Your usage is just fine.  I put in a little more clarification and ran on a handy cluster:

```
Calculated fibo( 31 ) =  1346269 with 4356617 calls
Calculated fibo( 32 ) =  2178309 with 7049155 calls
Calculated fibo( 33 ) =  3524578 with 11405773 calls
Calculated fibo( 34 ) =  5702887 with 18454929 calls
```

You're making over 40M calls to `fibo`; that might have slow response, depending on which Xeon(R) is running your box.  If you want to speed things up, try dynamic programming / memoization:

calls = 0
memo = {0:0, 1:1}

```
def fibo(n):
    global calls, memo

    calls += 1
    # if n> 0 and n%10 == 0: print("ENTER n =", n)
    if n not in memo:
        memo[n] = fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2)
    return memo[n]
```

Output:

```
Calculated fibo( 31 ) =  1346269 with 61 calls
Calculated fibo( 32 ) =  2178309 with 63 calls
Calculated fibo( 33 ) =  3524578 with 65 calls
Calculated fibo( 34 ) =  5702887 with 67 calls
```