# How to use with statement in lambda expression for Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, with-statement

I am using Python 3.5.2 (the one used for MS SQL Server Machine Learning Services).   I would like to have a `lambda` expression that uses with so not to repeat an expensive calculation in a tuple. A minimal example is

```
lambda x : 
  with x**2 as x2, x**3 as x3 :
    [ (x2**3)*x3-x3 , x2, (x3-5)**x2 ]
```

However, this returns a syntax error.  How is a `with` statement used in a `lambda` expression?

I am coming from Wolfram Language where this can be done. For example

```
With[{x2 = #^2, x3 = #^3},
  { (x2^3)*x3-x3 , x2, (x3-5)^x2 }
]&
```

I have a collection of these tiny calculations that are only needed in a small part of the code (within another function). I want to hold these as lambda functions to select and `apply`/`map` based particular conditions in that function.

Comment: Why not use a regular `def`?

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't possible; it's just not what lambdas are designed for. Make a function.

Comment: A Lambda can contain exactly one *expression*, so this isn't possible by definition.

Comment: That's not what context managers are designed for either.

Comment: @khelwood  I have a collection of tiny calculations that are only needed in a small part of the code (within another function). So it seems reasonable to hold these as lambda functions to select based particular conditions in that function.

Comment: @Edmund as "reasonnable" as it might seem, that's not how python works (neither `lambda` nor `with`). The fact that it can be done that way in another language is also irrelevant - by definition, different languages are, well, different, you know ?-)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Not saying the fact that it can be done that way in another language means it should be able to be done that way in Python.  Merely providing background as to why I thought this was possible and may have been missing the correct syntax to do so.  No need to be so salty, mate.

Comment: @Edmund sorry, but it just looked like you expected Python to work just like Wolfram. This being said, you'll probably save yourself a lot of time, pain and frustration by doing the official Python tutorial (and then browsing the doc). Also, note that while Python has some support for functional programming idioms, it's still not  a proper functional language - it's really an object language -, so functional idioms might not always be the most efficients.

Comment: Oh and yes: if you have a lot of numeric calculations to do, you may want to have a look at packages like numpy.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes, not as near to a functional programming as I initially thought. Now that I am using it it is definitely OOP with a slight wink to functional programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, this is spelled:

```
def fun1(x):
    x2 = x**2
    x3 = x**3 
    return [(x2**3) * x3 - x3 , x2, (x3 - 5) ** x2]
```

**EDIT**:

A couple more points...

First: someone mentions in a comment tha you could cache computation results for improved performances. It's indeed a common pattern usually named memoization, [which is rather easy to implement in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1988826/41316). Just note that this only works properly with [pure functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), and is of course only beneficial if the memoized function is repeatedly called with the same arguments.

Second point, you mention that:

> I have taken this route and defined the mini functions within the function.

You have to know that in Python, `def` is an executable statement that creates a new `function` object (yes, Python functions are objects - actually everything in Python is an object) when executed.

This means that "top-level" functions (functions defined at the top-level of a module) are created once when the module is first imported in the current process, but that inner (nested) functions are created anew each time the outer (enclosing) function is called.

Also, [Python functions are closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)), so a nested function can capture the environment of the outer function (and it's the main - and only as far as I'm concerned - reason for using nested functions in Python).

This means that you can use inner functions as another way to cache some precomputed values and make them available to a set of functions, ie:

```
def outer(x, y):
    x2 = x ** 2
    x3 = x ** 3

    def func1():
        return [(x2**3) * x3 - x3 , x2, (x3 - 5) ** x2]

    def func2(z):
        # dummy example
        return (x2**y) + (y - x3 ** z)

    # etc

    results = [func2(i) for i in func1()]
    return results
```

On the other hand, if your "helper" functions are not dependant on their enclosing scope, the only thing you get from defining them within the outer function is the overhead of creating the same functions again and again and again each time the outer function is called. It's of course not a problem if the outer func is only called once or twice per process, but if it's invoked in a tight loop the overhead can quickly become an issue.

Comment: So the only way to proceed is to create named functions for all of these small calculations and then reference them by name in the dataframe column?

Comment: @Edmund Not by name. You pass the function object. Where you're currently doing `lambda: ...`, you instead do `fun1`. And yes, they will have to be named.

Comment: If you want to avoid repeating your expensive calculation, it only makes sense you cache the results somehow i.e. naming them to be referred back later.  Even in your example your logic is essentially naming them, just in a different context that's not valid syntax for Python.

Comment: I have taken this route and defined the mini functions within the function. If the number of them grows I will most likely pull them out into a package. But this is working for now.  Thanks!

Comment: @Edmund beware that in Python `def` is an executable statement, so inner (nested) function are created anew on call of the outer function. Depending on your use case this may (or not) have some impact on performances.

Comment: @Edmund you may want to check my edited answer for more on inner functions and how to use (or not to use) them ;-)

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3.8, you can write

```
lambda x: [ (x2 := x**2) * (x3:=x**3) - x3, x2, (x3 - 5) ** x2 ]
```

However, that's not terribly readable. I would still just use a `def` statement to define a named function, as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57976808/1126841.

(Perhaps some future version of Python will find a way to support functional-style let expressions like

```
let x2 := x**2, x3 := x**3 in (x2*x3 - x3, x2, (x3-5) ** x2)
```

but I wouldn't hold my breath. This really requires the keywords for readability, and there is strong resistance--with good reason, I'll admit--to introducing new keywords or overloading existing keywords.)

Comment: Thanks for the insight. If SQL Server upgrades their Machine Learning Services to 3.*+ then I might switch to this implementation. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

In the Python implementation, a lambda expression must be evaluable, i.e., something that you can pass into the `eval()` function. In Python, not everything is evaluable. For example, assignment operation (`a=3`) is not evaluable, function calls are always evaluable (even if a function does not return anything, i.e., it evaluates to `None`). As a result, since the `with` statement is NOT evaluable (i.e., it does not evaluate into anything), both `eval()` and `lambda` do not accept it.

As a workaround, you can use `exec()` into a lambda expression, because it evaluates to None by definition.

In practice, the only usefulness of using the `with` statement in lambda is code succinctness which is an important aspect in measuring a programmer's expertise level. To achieve the same task, a novice programmer needs dozens of lines and hundreds of characters of code while a expert programmer only needs a dozen characters within a single line of code. For example, you can use 1 line of code to define a function saving a JSON config file,

```
save_config = lambda obj: exec("with open('.config.json','w') as fp: json.dump(obj, fp, indent=1)")
```

Regarding the OP's example, his intention is to avoid recomputing `x**2` and `x**3` over and over again as it might occur many times in the target expression. Thus, you need assignment operator to precompute `x2` and `x3`, but assignment operator is not evaluable. So, the trick here is to use within-bracket `for` loop and using single-item for the `for` loop:

```
>>> L=lambda x:[[ (x2**3)*x3-x3 , x2, (x3-5)**x2 ] for x2 in [x**2] for x3 in [x**3]][0]
>>> L(1.5)
[35.068359375, 2.25, (2.1081673071098876+2.1081673071098863j)]
```

Well, to hack it a bit, you can use `exec()` to assign x2 and x3, and extract the wanted element using list, but it runs much slower:

```
>>> L=lambda x: [exec('x2=x**2;x3=x**3',globals(),globals()),[ (x2**3)*x3-x3 , x2, (x3-5)**x2 ]][1]
>>> L(1.5)
[35.068359375, 2.25, (2.1081673071098876+2.1081673071098863j)]
```

Comment: The `for` loop is a creative workaround.  Thanks. +1