# How can I optimize my code to print amicable numbers?

Tags: python, optimization

I have tried this following code and it takes a lot of time when I set lower = 0 and upper = 10000

```
def sumPdivisors(n):
  '''This function returns the sum of proper divisors of a number'''
  lst = []
  for i in range(1,n//2+1):
    if n%i == 0:
      lst.append(i)
  return(sum(lst))

lower = int(input("Enter the lower value of range: "))
upper = int(input("Enter the upper value of range: "))

lst = []

for i in range(lower, upper+1):
    if i == 0:
      continue
    else:
      for j in range(i, upper):
        if i!=j and sumPdivisors(i) == j and sumPdivisors(j) == i:
          lst.append((i,j))
          break

print(lst)
```

Comment: precomputing (and storing in a list) sumPdivisors(i) for all i's in range(lower, upeer) seems a good start.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things that you could do here.

**Memoization**

There's already a great explanation of what memoization is elsewhere on this site [[link]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988804/what-is-memoization-and-how-can-i-use-it-in-python/1988826#1988826), but here's how it's relevant to your problem:

- `sumPdivisors` is called very frequently in the for-loop at the bottom of your code snippet. For really large inputs `n`, it will take a long time to run.
- `sumPdivisors` is called with the same input `n` multiple times.
- You can speed things up by *saving* the result of calling `sumPdivisors` on different inputs somehow, like in a dictionary that maps integers to the resulting output when you call `sumPdivisors` with that corresponding integer. This is kind of what memoization is. You're precomputing the possible outputs of `sumPdivisors` and storing them for later. Read the link for a more in-depth explanation.

**Don't add the numbers in sumPdivisors to a list**

You can just add these numbers as you iterate instead of appending them to a list, then summing them. This change won't have as great of an impact as adding memoization to your code.