# Memoization and return statements

Tags: python, return, memoization

I am fairly new to python, stumbled upon a dynamic programming course on youtube that I thought would help me better understand the concept @ [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBt53YbR9Kk&t=6228s).

Now, I have been struggling to understand it... Would anyone have the time to explain the way this code works?

The function takes a target sum and an array of numbers as arguments.
The function should return an array containing any combination of numbers that add up exactly to the target number.

```
def howSum(targetSum, numbers, memo = {}):

if targetSum in memo : return memo[targetSum]
if targetSum == 0 : return []
if targetSum < 0 : return None

for num in numbers:
    remainder = targetSum - num
    
    remainderResult = howSum(remainder, numbers, memo)
        
    if remainderResult != None:
        memo[targetSum] = [*remainderResult, num]
        return memo[targetSum]
    
memo[targetSum] = None
return None
```

The original code was written for JS, I translated it to Python but I am struggling with a couple of things: namely:

- return statements at the end of the definition
- and this line specificaly:

  memo[targetSum] = [*remainderResult, num]

Is there a concept I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to explain by comments:

```
def howSum(targetSum, numbers, memo = {}):

    # if the result is calculated 
    # already (in the past) then 
    # use it
    if targetSum in memo : return memo[targetSum]

    # return pre-defined values 
    # to out-of-bound parameters
    if targetSum == 0 : return []
    if targetSum < 0 : return None

    # otherwise make the calculation
    for num in numbers:
        remainder = targetSum - num
        
        remainderResult = howSum(remainder, numbers, memo)
            
        if remainderResult != None:
            # if there is a result (which is not 
            # None) then store it for later
            # (to memoize it)
            memo[targetSum] = [*remainderResult, num]
            return memo[targetSum]
    
    memo[targetSum] = None
    return None
```

For a more pythonic memoization see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988804/what-is-memoization-and-how-can-i-use-it-in-python).

Comment: Thank you for the link. time to study a bit more

Comment: if you found it useful, please consider upvoting :)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to mention in short the function your code supposed to evaluate to save others' time.

1. > return statements at the end of the definition:

note that if you arrive this line while executing the code, then you didn't find an answer, so return None, which means no answer is found.

2. > memo[targetSum] = [*remainderResult, num]

Your function tries to find a way to write targetSum as the sum of a subset of elements in numbers, and store these elements in memo[targetSum]. This is exactly what happens in this line of code.

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the post based on your comment.