# Does return keyword in Python saves the value in memory for a function with an specific parameter?

Tags: python, function, recursion, memory, return-value

I'm learning about recursive functions, and I have a doubt, let's say:

```
def fibonacci(n):
if n == 0 or n == 1:
    return 1

return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)

fibonacci(4)
fibonacci(5)
```

When the program executes `fibonacci(5)`, which would be like:

```
fibonacci(5) = fibonacci(4) + fibonacci(3)
```

Does Python have to calculate again the last two functions using recursion, or would it have the result already saved in memory as it already executed the same function with those same parameters when it executed `fibonacci(4)` and so would instantly assign them their values?

Comment: "Does Python have to calculate again the last two functions using recursion" Yes, of course. How else could this work? You expect Python to cache the result of *every function call by default*? That isn't in principle even desirable unless they are pure functions, and that isn't even getting into the memory requirements.

Comment: In any case, did you *try* this, e.g. putting a `print` inside your `fibonacci` function and seeing what happens?

Comment: You're probably looking for memoizing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization , though there are a variety of other great optimizations for calculating the fibonacci series!

Comment: This offers `functools.lru_cache` https://stackoverflow.com/a/14731729/4541045 .. the docs for which actually show its use around a Fibonacci series https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache

Comment: as additional reading - look at [functools.lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, **there is no automatic caching for function calls in Python**. If you call `fibonacci(6)` and then `fibonacci(5)`, Python will call all of the associated functions once more, even though it is redundant.

What you are talking about (caching and such) is called *memoization* and is the foundational principle of a larger concept called Dynamic Programming. DP is basically a way of taking a basic recursion (like your fibonacci implementation) and making it more efficient by applying some techniques (like caching)

Here is a pretty good website that explains this concept pretty well and actually uses the fibonacci series as an example. [What is Dynamic Programming](https://www.educative.io/courses/grokking-dynamic-programming-patterns-for-coding-interviews/m2G1pAq0OO0)