# Number of even XOR-ed subarrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, performance, dynamic-programming

Find the number of subarrays with even XOR (XOR of subarray means XOR of its elements).
For eg:

```
l=[1,2,3,4]   # ----> Answer of this is 4
```

(Explanation: [2],[4],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]---> These are the subarrays which have XOR even, hence number of subarrays=4)

Here is my code:

```
def odd_int(lst):
    odd=0
    for i in lst:
        if i%2!=0:
            odd+=1 
    return odd    
l=list(map(int,input().split()))
x=0 # Denotes number of even xor arrays
for i in range(len(l)):
    for j in range(i,len(l)):
        l1=l[i:j+1]
        y=odd_int(l1)
        if y%2==0:
            x+=1
print(x)
```

The above code exceeds time limit, so any suggestions to optimise it to O(n)???
Thanks for your time!!!

Comment: Can you share how big is the `input array` size? Maybe consider using the `dict` to reduce time to O(n)?  instead.

Comment: Input array can be as big as 100000, so now you can decide

Comment: Your solution is O(n^3). Notice that the first two loops on `i` and `j` calculate subarrays in O(n^2) time. However, your `odd_int` function takes in a list and re-computes the XOR, which itself is O(n). You should focus first on reducing to O(n^2) first (not too difficult) then attempting to further optimize if needed. Steadily reducing the computations used should help you arrive at the desired result.

Comment: There's a O(n) solution, I believe the hashmap with prefix calculation can achieve that.

Answer (score 9):

XOR has some nice properties that allow a linear-time solution using constant words of extra space.

The first property (formally: commutative, associative, every element is self-inverse) gives a way to compute arbitrary subarray XORs quickly. If we take the prefix XORs

```
prefixXORs[0] = 0
prefixXORs[1] = prefixXORs[0] ^ l[0] = 1
prefixXORs[2] = prefixXORs[1] ^ l[1] = 3
prefixXORs[3] = prefixXORs[2] ^ l[2] = 0
prefixXORs[4] = prefixXORs[3] ^ l[3] = 4
```

then we can compute

```
l[i] ^ ... ^ l[j] == prefixXORs[i] ^ prefixXORs[j + 1]
```

Thus the problem becomes determining how many pairs of prefix XORs have even XOR.

The second property is that

```
even ^ even is even
even ^ odd is odd
odd ^ even is odd
odd ^ odd is even
```

Thus we can count the number of pairs of prefix XORs where both are even or both are odd. In Python:

```
def count_even_subarrays(l):
    prefixXOR = 0
    evens = 1
    odds = 0
    for x in l:
        prefixXOR ^= x
        if prefixXOR % 2 == 0:
            evens += 1
        else:
            odds += 1
    return evens * (evens - 1) // 2 + odds * (odds - 1) // 2


print(count_even_subarrays([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Comment: Great explanations. Thumb up.

Comment: I have understood most part of the question but please explain just two things:  i.) What are evens and odds in the above, do they refer to number of even and odd xor? ii.) Why did we do even(even-1//2) in the end and add that with odd(odd-1//2)? What is that for??

Comment: @OliverQueen `evens` and `odds` are the number of prefix XORs that are even and odd respectively. `n*(n-1)//2` is the fornula for number of ways to make unordered pairs with `n` items.

Answer (score 1):

**Idea**: Find the number of subarrays whose sum is even (divisible by 2).

**Thought Process :**

Here are some properties of XOR operation

- even ^ even = even
- odd  ^ odd  = even
- even ^ odd  = odd
- odd  ^ even = odd

1. Now from the above properties, we can observe that in a subarray if the number of even elements is even and the number of odd elements is even then we can say that the XOR of that subarray is even.
   e.g; (odd ^ even ^ odd ^ even ) => (even ^ even ^ odd ^ odd) => (even ^ even) ^ (odd ^ odd) => (even ^ even) => even.
2. Now as the number of odd elements and even elements is even in a subarray, so the sum of the subarray is also even(divisible by 2).
3. As mentioned in the 2nd point you must find the number of subarrays whose sum is divisible by 2. you can refer to this as a reference (https://leetcode.com/problems/subarray-sums-divisible-by-k/) this is the problem for finding the number of subarrays whose sum is divisible by k, but in our case here k = 2.

- Time Complexity: O(n)
- Space Complexity: O(1)
- refer above link for the approach and complexities.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that you could try is to use [memoization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988804/what-is-memoization-and-how-can-i-use-it-in-python) pattern using `functools.lru_cache`:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def odd_int(lst):
    odd=0
    for i in lst:
        if i%2!=0:
            odd+=1 
    return odd    

def xor_list(input_list):
    #l=list(map(int,input_list.split()))
    l = tuple(input_list)  # required for LRU cache to work (hashable input to the odd_int function needed)
    x=0 # Denotes number of even xor arrays
    for i in range(len(l)):
        for j in range(i,len(l)):
            l1=l[i:j+1]
            y=odd_int(l1)
            if y%2==0:
                x+=1
    #print(x)
```

The timings are:

your code:

> 15.8 ms ± 2.57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

with memoization:

> 3.35 ms ± 210 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

It is likely that you can improve further by moving the `y%2` checking to the function as well.

You can eliminate calls to `odd_int` entirely by pre-processing the whole array and fetching the value in constant time from an additional list instead of doing this in the body of two `for` loops. But I will leave this for you to implement and check.

Comment: Any way to eliminate for loops, cause I dont think that this question requires the use of external library!!!!

Comment: You can implement memoization pattern yourself. And `functools` is in the standard library.

Comment: That was my question all along, to eliminate two for loops and reduce time complexity . I have been trying to do this since days and I couldnt come up with O(n) solution, so if you can help, please do!! I have tried my best on this one!!!

Comment: Also, its now showing memory limit exceeded

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple recurrence that allows for an `O(n)` time, `O(1)` space algorithm:

```py
def f(A):
  total, odd, even = 0, 0, 0
  for a in A:
    even, odd = (odd, 1 + even) if a % 2 else (1 + even, odd)
    total += even
  return total


# Test

import random

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/65801048/2034787
def eisenstat(l):
    prefixXOR = 0
    evens = 1
    odds = 0
    for x in l:
        prefixXOR ^= x
        if prefixXOR % 2 == 0:
            evens += 1
        else:
            odds += 1
    return evens * (evens - 1) // 2 + odds * (odds - 1) // 2

num_tests = 100

for _ in range(num_tests):
  A = random.sample(range(10, 100), 10)
  if f(A) != eisenstat(A):
    print(A)
```

Comment: @OliverQueen no. They are both O(n) time and O(1) space complexity. It's just another way of thinking about it.