# Is there an efficient way of invoking this recursive function only once?

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion

Here is a code that finds the value of the function `T` given by the recurrence relation for a given value of `n`:

```
def T(n):
  if n <= 0:
    return 1
  else:
    return T(n-1) + (n-1) * T(n-2)
    
print T(3)

#output
2
```

However, the code invokes the function *T* twice. I have added the `print` statement before the second `return` to show this:

```
def T(n):
  if n <= 0:
    return 1
  else:
    print (T(n-1) + (n-1) * T(n-2))
    return T(n-1) + (n-1) * T(n-2)
    
print T(3)

#output
1
2
1
2
```

Is there an efficient way of invoking the function *T* only once? I'm using Python 2. I'd like something short and simple, nothing too complicated.

Comment: Unrelated, but please use python3

Comment: Pass an argument that is less than or equal to zero.  What exactly do you expect from a recursive function?

Comment: It invokes `T` *four* times, not two: twice each in the `print` and the `return`.  Is your problem with the extra output?  If so, then quit printing intermediate results from within the recursive function.  You haven't explained what you're *really* trying to achieve.

Comment: @OneCricketeer - I am currently having problems with the Python 3 software that I'm using which is why I'm using Python 2 for the time being.

Comment: What kind of problems? Your code runs the exact same in python3 if you simply fixed the print statements

Comment: @OneCricketeer - I've stated that I'm using Python 2 so that users don't answer the question with functions that aren't compatible with python 2.

Comment: @Prune - I have edited my question. Is it clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the function from `T(n) = T(n-1) + (n-1)*T(n-2)` to `T(n+1) = T(n) + n*T(n-1)` which will allow the recursion to move forward rather than backward provided you give it the current n and previous values.  By only needing the previous value instead of the two previous values, the recursive progression is easier to grasp.

```
def T(N,n=1,Tm=1,Tn=1):  # n,Tm,Tn represent n,T(n-1),T(n)
    if n>N: return Tm    # stop at n=N+1 and return T(n-1)
    return T(N,n+1,Tn,Tn+n*Tm)
```

*note: the function returns `a` when `n>N` in order to cover the case where `N` is zero.*

Actually, this could also have been written without transposing the function by moving the stop condition to N+2 instead of N+1:

```
def T(N,n=2,Tn_2=1,Tn_1=1):   # n,Tn_2,Tn_1 represent n,T(n-2),T(n-1)
    if n==N+2: return Tn_2    # stop at n=N+2 and return T(n-2)
    return T(N,n+1,Tn_1,Tn_1+(n-1)*Tn_2)
```

which can be further simplified to:

```
def T(N,n=1,a=1,b=1): return T(N-1,n+1,b,a*n+b) if N else a
```

Comment: Also, could you explain the a, b, and c part of your code? This might just be the code I was looking for...

Comment: Changed the parameter names and added comments to better convey what's going on.

Comment: Also, why are the a,b, and n values set to 1?

Comment: Those are the initial states that correspond to T(0)

Comment: If I want to check each step of the recursion process, how do I do this?

Comment: You can print n, a and b at the beginning of the function

Comment: I'm sorry for asking so many questions, but is it possible for you to explain this in a bit more detail? "provided you give it the current n and previous values. By only needing the previous value instead of the two previous values, the recursive progression is easier to grasp."

Comment: What I meant by this is that the values we carry as parameters only need to represent T(n) and T(n-1)  instead of T(n-1) and T(n-2) which would require that we define T(-1) and T(-2)  at some point to cover the case of T(0) and T(1).  By starting with the values of T(0) and T(1) and exiting at n>N, we don't need to define values for negative Ns.

Answer (score 3):

You're going to call T 2^(n-1) times, for n >1, and there is no way to reduce that to only once without removing the recursion.

If you meant to say that you want to reduce the repetitive calls, such as T(3) calls T(2) and T(1) while T(2) also calls T(1), then you need to use a process called *memoization*

For example, using a dictionary of inputs to results.

```
seen = dict() 

def T(n):
  if n <= 0:
    return 1
  else:
    if n in seen:
        return seen[n] 
    else:
        result = T(n-1) + (n-1) * T(n-2)
        seen[n] = result
        return result 

print(T(3))
```

Comment: Could you explain what the `dict()` function does in this context?

Comment: Same as `T.cache = {}`. Defines an empty dictionary

Comment: I think this is good but I think memoization on the function would be cleaner (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988804/what-is-memoization-and-how-can-i-use-it-in-python)