# Memoization in DP problem to create all possible expressions by using symbol + / -

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, memoization

I was solving [target sum problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/target-sum/) on leetcode which asks us to use either +/- symbol on all integers and then check sum of array is equal to target.
I'm trying to return all possible combinations using this symbols using recursion
This is my current code which works but is not optimized

```
nums=[1,1,1]
res=[]
def recursion(i,temp,res):
    if i==len(nums):
        res.append(temp[:])
        return
    temp.append(nums[i])
    recursion(i+1,temp,res)
    temp.pop()
    temp.append(-1*nums[i])
    recursion(i+1,temp,res)
    temp.pop()
recursion(0,[],res)
print(res)
```

Result of this program is:
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, -1], [1, -1, 1], [1, -1, -1], [-1, 1, 1], [-1, 1, -1], [-1, -1, 1], [-1, -1, -1]]
Can someone please help me to understand how can I memoize it?

Comment: There is already a good explanation on Stackoverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988804/what-is-memoization-and-how-can-i-use-it-in-python

Comment: I know how to use memoization but I have not seen any problem where you need to store list of list as value pair for key. Any direction on this will be helpful

Comment: For this kind of problem, you don't need to generate all possible combinations but count those that form the target sum.