# Recursive function remembers the last result as an argument

Tags: python, list, recursion

I'm trying to split a number into powers of 2, but my function remembers the result of my previous call.

```
from math import log

#split number in powers of 2
#n   :  number
#lst :  the current list of numbers
def spn(n, lst=list()):
    if n==1:
        lst.append(n)
        return lst
    else:
        #rdy  :  the ready-to-add number
        rdy=2**((log(n+1,2))-1)
        lst.append(rdy)
        #n-rdy:  the new number to evaluate
        return spn(n-rdy, lst)
```

For example:

- `spn(1)` should return `[1]`
- `spn(3)` should return `[2.0, 1.0]`
- `spn(7)` should return `[4.0, 2.0, 1.0]`

But it only works the first time I call the function then after the first call my previous result appears as an argument:

[image]

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676729/why-does-using-none-fix-pythons-mutable-default-argument-issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `lst` argument default value to `None`, and if it is None then instantiate it inside your function.

Read about the Python [Gotchas](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/category/python-gotchas/) on why using mutable default argument values are bad.