# Find specific sum in a 2D array - python algorithms

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, recursion

We are given a 2D array and asked to write a fuction that will search the array for a specific subset of elements that sum up to the given target sum and return True, if it finds the subset and False otherwise. The specificity of this subset is the condition that any two of the elements must not be taken from the same column or row of the 2D array. For example, for an array:
`T=[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,5,6,7], [2,4,6,8]]`
and target sum: target_sum = 26
the output should be True, because T[0][1]+T[1][2]+T[2][0]+T[3][3] == 2+7+9+8 == 26,
The same for the same array and target_sum = 20, because T[0][0]+T[1][3]+T[2][1]+T[3][2]==20

This is what I tried:

```
def given_sum(T, target_sum, row=-1, current_sum=0, columns=set()):

    if target_sum==current_sum:
        return True
    if current_sum>target_sum:
        return False
    if row>=len(T)-1:
        return False
    row+=1
    for col in range(len(T)):
        if col in columns:
            continue
        columns.add(col)
        return given_sum(T, target_sum, row, current_sum+T[row][col],columns)
        columns.remove(col)
```

For the example array as above:
`T=[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,5,6,7], [2,4,6,8]]`
and target_sum = 21, it prints True, because T[0][0]+T[1][1]+T[2][2]+T[3][3]==21,
but for target_sum = 26, it prints False despite the fact that T[0][1]+T[1][2]+T[2][0]+T[3][3]==26
Please help!

Comment: Here are some questions need to be clarified - is the answer always ```unique```?  In the example, ```1+8+9+8``` also satisfied (26).

Comment: Just return True if such a subset exists and False if it doesn't exist - no, the answer doesn't need to be unique

Comment: If you squint your eyes, you will see that the exploration of the solutions of the problem is tree-shaped. So a recursive implementation seems possible, but not necessarily easy. What is your problem ? "why does my code produces the wrong output" ? Why did you return False for 26, and True for 21 ? That is a debugging question. [What is a debugger and how can it help me ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems). Currently your question looks like "fix my code please".

Answer (score 0):

Just putting your code in my IDE tells me that :

- your `columns.remove` call is unreachable (being after a `return` statement)
- your `columns` function parameter is **mutable**, this looks like a footgun ! see [Why does PyCharm warn about mutable default arguments? How can I work around them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41686829/11384184)

Then adding `given_sum(T=[[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,5,6,7], [2,4,6,8]], target_sum=26)`, putting three debug points (one on each `return True` or `False`, which are your terminal cases), and I get :

`row >= len(T) - 1` eveluates to `True`, so it bubbles up that `False`.

No sum was really checked, so I think your algorithm is wrong.
A debugger can get you there very fast.