# Question on calling dictionaries properly in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm writing some network programming code where I'd like to pass in dictionaries optionally, if the dictionary is recieved by the called function in executes another function. I assumed setting dictionary to Nonetype was the way to go, when I did this I got a "dict is not callable" error. The dictionary in my case is napalm_results_dict. However I wound up fixing it and it works with dict=None. i thought this was very interesting and decided to share it here, look at the napalm_results_dict:

Here is my code:

```
get_configurations_threaded(device_connections, config_dict_before, routing_dict_before, napalm_results_dict)

def get_configurations_threaded(device_connections, config_dict_before  ={}, routing_dict_before = {}, napalm_results_dict = None):
    threads = []
    for device, (device_type, device_ip, username, password, secret) in device_connections.items():
        if napalm_results_dict is None:
            thread = threading.Thread(target=get_configuration, args=(device, device_ip, device_type, config_dict_before, routing_dict_before))
        else:
            thread = threading.Thread(target=get_configuration, args=(device, device_ip, device_type, config_dict_before, routing_dict_before, napalm_results_dict))
        threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
        # print(threading.current_thread().name)

# we can overload get_configuration, and get_configurations_threaded with extra functions, to obtain results other than get_config, or format them into classes
def get_configuration(device, device_ip, device_type, config_dict_before={}, routing_dict_before={}, napalm_results_dict =None):
    try:
        config = device.get_config()
        config_dict_before[device_ip] = config


        # routing_info = device._send_command("show ip route")
        # device_parser = DeviceParser(device_ip, routing_dict_before)
        # device_parser.parse_routing_info(routing_info)
        # Optionally call napalm_functions: We do this to get everything in one go, optionally
        if napalm_results_dict is not None:
            print("Running NAPALM results dict")
            napalm_results = napalm_functions(device)
            napalm_results_dict[device_ip] = napalm_results
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to retrieve configuration for {device_ip}: {str(e)}")
    finally:
        print(threading.current_thread().name)

def napalm_functions(device, result_dict=None): #the result_dict = None allows us to call this  in via get_configurations, or call this function directly by passing in a dict
    result_dict = {}
    # List of functions to call
    functions = [
        device.get_bgp_neighbors,
        device.get_environment,
        device.get_arp_table,
        # device.get_route_to("0.0.0.0"),  # Using lambda for functions with arguments
        device.get_facts,
        device.get_ntp_stats]
    # Iterate through functions
    for func in functions:
        result = func()
        result_dict[func.__name__] = result
    return result_dict

def threaded_napalm(device_connections, result_dict = None):
    for device, (device_type, device_ip, username, password, secret) in device_connections.items():

        threads = []
        for func in functions:
            thread = threading.Thread(target=napalm_functions, args=(device,))
            thread.start()
            threads.append(thread)
        # Wait for all threads to finish
        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()
            # we include an optional result_dict in funciton signature so we can pass it in directly or pass the function to a dict itself
        return result_dict
```

Funny passing a dict type throughout the signature, or mutating it to a dict type by will, and having other functions conditionally run because of this.

Any comments to enlighten my understanding are appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a stack-trace / line number for that error or a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because I don't see where this error shall appear. As a side-note: You use empty dictionaries as default values. This is usually an error or at least a hazard, see for example the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41686829/why-does-pycharm-warn-about-mutable-default-arguments-how-can-i-work-around-the#41686973) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: @Homer512  I figured out the error in passing in an empty dict here: thread = threading.Thread(target=get_configuration, args=(device, device_ip, device_type, config_dict_before, routing_dict_before, napalm_results_dict)):  This was interesting to me in that I was receiving a Nonetype error, so I made an if else regarding that code and it worked. Took a little while to debug, and I was wondering on anyone's insight as to this.