Is it possible to have a default value that depends on a previous parameter?
Suppose I want to write a recursive binary search function in Python. The recursive function needs to get the start and end of the current search interval as parameters:
def binary_search(myarray, start, end): ...

But, when I call the actual function from outside, I always start at 0 and finish at the end of the array. It is easy to make 0 a default value for start, but how can I write a default value for end? Is it possible to write something like:
def binary_search(myarray, start=0, end=len(myarray)): ...

?

Default values (in functions) are defined during compiling time,ie., when the module where binary_search() is imported. So, no, you cannot do that (dinamically, as proposed).

The common idiom* is:
def binary_search(myarray, start=0, end=None):
    if end is None:
        end = len(myarray)

*(usually used to avoid a mutable default argument value, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41686973/5052365)
