# How do I implicitly define a parameter to an empty list?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

In the code below, I've been wondering how we could tell if a parameter, `b`, is given.

The problem is that the third call of `func` does not retain `[5]` in a newly created list but rather some pointer in the start that `b` is pointing to. I'm guessing this is defined before in the program stack entering `func` call itself, so the calling and returning of `func` would not change `b`...?

Any insight is appreciated.

```py
def func(a, b=[]):

    b.append([a])
    print(b)
    return b

func(3)
func(4, [])
func(5)
```

Comment: `func(a, b=None): b = b if b is not None else []` see e.g. https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/

Comment: Related reading: ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does using `arg=None` fix Python's mutable default argument issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676729/why-does-using-arg-none-fix-pythons-mutable-default-argument-issue)

Comment: @hiroprotagonist perfect

Comment: Thank you all for the pointers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to assign the default value of b to something arbitrary (usually `None`) then check if b is defined that way:

```
def func(a, b=None):
    if b is None:
        b = []

    b.append([a])
    print(b)
    return b

func(3)
func(4, [])
func(5)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the idea. I'm doing more research into why and how this is part of the design ..

Comment: It has to do with the fact that functions are objects in python. They are only defined once. http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can define b to a default value, e.g. `b=None`, and then pick either the value of b if given, or pick an empty list.

```
def func(a, b=None):

    lst = b or []
    lst.append([a])
    print(lst)
    return lst

func(3)
#[[3]]
func(4, [])
#[[4]]
func(5)
#[[5]]
```