# Mutable default argument in built-ins

Tags: python

We all know the ['dreaded mutable default argument'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

I was surprised to find that there is at least one built-in that uses a mutable default argument, `deepcopy` (and the related `__deepcopy__`).

`def deepcopy(x, memo=None, _nil=[]):`

[source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f381cfe07d15d52f27de771a62a8167668f0dd51/Lib/copy.py#L137)

Is this just an overlook by the module's authors or is there something special about `deepcopy`'s behavior that justifies this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is intentional, the object is being used as a unique *sentinel object*. It is never itself mutated, nor are the list object contents ever inspected. It's only purpose is to have a unique object that can be used in an `is` test.

It is more common to use `None` as a sentinel to test if something has not been set, but you sometimes need to allow for `None` to be a valid set value. In the implementation of `deepcopy()` the `_nil` object is used to replace `None`:

```
y = memo.get(d, _nil)
if y is not _nil:
    return y
```

This allows `memo[d] = None` to be set, as `memo.get(d)` would return `None` both if `memo[d]` exists or is missing:

```
>>> memo = {}; d = 'foo'
>>> _nil = []
>>> memo.get(d) is None
True
>>> memo.get(d, _nil) is _nil
True
>>> memo[d] = None
>>> memo.get(d) is None
True
>>> memo.get(d, _nil) is _nil
False
```

If you are thinking of using your own unique not-`None` sentinel object, these days you'd probably want to use `object()`. But `object()` didn't exist yet in the Python language when the `deepcopy()` function was written.

`_nil` is an argument to make it a *local variable*. This makes looking up the `_nil` reference much cheaper than if it were a global in the module, see [Why does Python code run faster in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241523/why-does-python-code-run-faster-in-a-function) This is important in a function that can easily be called *a lot* when used to copy a deep and wide structure of custom objects. So, as the initial underscore to the name suggests, `_nil` is an implementation detail.

Also see [Is there a way to set a default parameter equal to another parameter value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157272/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-default-parameter-equal-to-another-parameter-value)