# Can you create method with tuple of parameters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, parameters, parameter-passing

Can you do something like this in Python?

```
def give_me_your_three_favorite_things_in_each_given_category(
    food=(first, second, third), 
    color=(first, second, third))
    println(f"Your favorite foods are {food.first}, {food.second} and {food.third}")
    println(f"Your favorite colors are {color.first}, {color.second} and {color.third}")

give_me_your_three_favorite_things_in_each_given_category(
    food=(first="pizza", second="pasta", third="ice cream"),
    color=(first="black", second="blue", third="green")
```

Expected output:
"Your favorite foods are pizza, pasta and ice cream"
"Your favorite colors are black, blue and green"

Comment: Use dicts? `def ...(food, ...): println(f"...{food['first']}...")`, and `give...(food={'first': 'pizza', ...})`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to set a default parameter equal to another parameter value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157272/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-default-parameter-equal-to-another-parameter-value)

Comment: @deceze I want to have a method that specifies amount of parameters needed. Your and maor10 answers are good, but not in the case when you want user of this method to know exactly how many parameters to pass, and what those parameters mean exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure-
The way you would do it would be as follows:

```
def give_me_your_three_favorite_things_in_each_given_category(food, color):
    first_food, second_food, third_food = food
    print(f"Your favorite foods are {first_food}, {second_food}, {third_food}")
    first_color, second_color, third_color = color
    print(f"Your favorite colors are {first_color}, {second_color}, {third_color}")
```

You can see here that we receive tuples as paramaters, and then unpack them.

You can then call the function with

```
give_me_your_three_favorite_things_in_each_given_category(
food=("pizza", "pasta", "ice cream"),
color=("black", "blue", "green"))
```

You can also use named tuples so that you can have names for each value in the tuple:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Food = namedtuple("Food", ("first", "second", "third"))
Color = namedtuple("Color", ("first", "second", "third"))
give_me_your_three_favorite_things_in_each_given_category(
    food=Food(first="pizza", second="pasta", third="ice cream"),
    color=Color(first="black", second="blue", third="green")
)
```

Comment: Hmm, almost what im looking for.
But in my case i need to use parameter names that are inside a tuple

Comment: @Stanislaw Whatever does that mean exactly?

Comment: @deceze look at my post  
`method_name(tuple_name(first_parameter_name, second_parameter_name))`

Comment: @Stanislaw Your post shows a bunch of invalid code. It's unclear what part of that is important to you to get somewhat closely implemented, or whether it's all just a bad example. As I commented, why no dicts?

Comment: @deceze could you write it like maor10 did?

Comment: Dicts aren't the right solution here either- you never use dicts for data models with known parametrs. If you'd like it to be with parameter names, you can create a dataclass, or a namedtuple

Comment: so you could have 
from collections import namedtuple

Food = namedtuple("Food", ("first", "second", "third"))

Comment: @maor10 Its funny how you can understand my problem exactly :D