# Problems with instantiating list in constructor

Tags: python, list

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, label, children = []):
        self.label = label
        self.children = children

t1 = Tree("START")
t2 = Tree("END")
t1.children.append(t2)

print t2.children
[<__main__.Tree instance at 0x005421C0>]
```

Why isn't t2.children empty?

Comment: Check out the above link: everyone is surprised by this issue eventually. For suggestions of Pythonic ways to fix it, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366422/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-avoid-default-parameters-that-are-empty-lists

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the default value is executed only once - when the def statement is excuted.
Thus, all instance objects' children are assigned the same list.

In short, the lists for `t1` and `t2` are the same list.