# Accessing object attributes in a for loop results in same attribute [Python]

Tags: python

Using a for loop I am trying to append dictionaries to an object attribute:

```
do = direct_objects[0].point_logs
for direct_object in direct_objects: #Contains two objects
            print ( do is direct_object.point_logs) #Gives true both times
            do = direct_object.point_logs
            print(direct_object.id) #objects are different instances
            dates = generate_dates_interval('2017-01-01', '2017-04-01', 14) #Generates dates with an interval of 14 days for the given period

            for i in range(0, len(dates)-1):

                point_logs, interval_logs, cum_logs = get_point_logs(direct_object, dates[i],
                                                                     dates[i+1]) # gets logs for given period

                if point_logs is not None:
                    direct_object.point_logs.append(point_logs)
                if interval_logs is not None:
                    direct_object.interval_logs.append(interval_logs)
                if cum_logs is not None:
                    direct_object.cum_logs.append(cum_logs)
```

I want to loop through the dates and append all the logs to an instance of DirectObject's `point_logs`. However what I get is that, instead of being two seperate lists, the direct_object.point_logs becomes a a big list of all the point logs for both direct objects.

```
class DirectObject(object):
    def __init__(self, id, created_date, deleted_date, name, type, point_logs = [], interval_logs = [], cum_logs= [],
                 services = None):
        self.id = id
        self.created_date = created_date
        self.deleted_date = deleted_date
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.point_logs = point_logs
        self.interval_logs = interval_logs
        self.cum_logs = cum_logs
        self.services = services

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name) + " id: " + str(self.id) + " type: " + str(self.type)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.name) + " id: " + str(self.id) + " type: " + str(self.type)
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: It is though I am only using it for debugging purposes

Comment: `do` isn't a python keyword BTW. it's a `c` keyword. The mystery is why it is highlighted like a keyword.

Comment: The syntax highlighting got me :P

Comment: anyway, it's not a very good variable name.

Comment: the highlighting seems to have a language-merged keyword database, so C keywords appear highlighted as well.

Comment: direct_object.point_logs is a list and so is point_logs(probably). When you append a list to a list, it becomes a bigger list. What is wrong here?

Comment: @alDiablo That's correct, but I expect two direct_objects.point_logs lists (for the two different instances). Instead I get one direct_object.point_logs list.

Comment: Note: `point_logs = [], interval_logs = [], cum_logs= []`. This is a common [Python gotcha](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/category/python-gotchas)(not sure if the link is the best).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since everything is an object in Python, the empty list you use as the default argument is too an object. More importantly, it is the same object! Like writing `a = b = []`
You have to try other recipes, such as the one here.

[What is the pythonic way to avoid default parameters that are empty lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366422/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-avoid-default-parameters-that-are-empty-lists)

Comment: Thank you that answers my question