# Linked entries in a list of class instances

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, a=[None,None], b=[None,None], c=[None,None]):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

new = [test(), test()]
new[0].a[0] = 15
new[1].a
```

I cannot understand why the second entry changes as well. How did it turn out that both elements of the list "new" are the same object?

EDIT:
For the solution, try this link"
[What is the pythonic way to avoid default parameters that are empty lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366422/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-avoid-default-parameters-that-are-empty-lists)

Comment: check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument, basiclly all the list in there are shared

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect, but I didn't know how to google it. Is there something I should do with this question now? Close it somehow?

Comment: it is marked as duplicated and that is all, so anywone with the same doubts will be redirected to the other answer also. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Is there an answer someplace how to rewrite it properly to make it work?

Comment: Ah, found it. never mind!