# Weird Bug in Python Generator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an an implementation of Knuth's Algorithm ("dancing links") that behaves very strangely.  I've found a workaround, but it's like magic.  The script below tests the code on the N queens problem.  The bug occurs in the first function, `solve`.  The parameter `limit` is supposed to limit the number of solutions generated, and the default value of 0 means "generate all solutions".

```
#Test generalized exact cover for n queens problem 

def solve(Cols,  Rows, SecondaryIDs=set(), limit = 0):
    for soln in solver(Cols, Rows, SecondaryIDs):
        print('solve:', limit, soln)
        yield soln
        limit -= 1
        if limit == 0: return

def solver(Cols, Rows, SecondaryIDs, solution=[]):
    live=[col for col in Cols if col not in SecondaryIDs] 
    if not live:
        yield solution
    else:
        col = min(live, key = lambda col: len(Cols[col]))        
        for row in list(Cols[col]):                                          
            solution.append(row)                                            
            columns = select(Cols, Rows, row)                        
            for soln in solver(Cols, Rows, SecondaryIDs, solution):
                yield soln
            deselect(Cols, Rows, row, columns)
            solution.pop()

def select(Cols, Rows, row):
    columns = []
    for col in Rows[row]:
        for rrow in Cols[col]:
            for ccol in Rows[rrow]:
                if ccol != col:
                    Cols[ccol].remove(rrow)
        columns.append(Cols.pop(col))  
    return columns

def deselect(Cols, Rows, row, columns): 
    for col in reversed(Rows[row]):
        Cols[col] = columns.pop()
        for rrow in Cols[col]:
            for ccol in Rows[rrow]:
                if ccol != col:
                    Cols[ccol].add(rrow)

n = 5

# From Dancing Links paper
solutionCounts = {4:2, 5:10, 6:4, 7:40, 8:92, 9:352, 10:724}

def makeRows(n):
    # There is one row for each cell.    
    rows = dict()
    for rank in range(n):
        for file in range(n):
            rows["R%dF%d"%(rank,file)] = ["R%d"%rank, "F%d"%file, "S%d"%(rank+file), "D%d"%(rank-file)]
    return rows

def makePrimary(n):
    # One primary column for each rank and file
    prim = dict()
    for rank in range(n):
        prim["R%d"%rank] = {"R%dF%d"%(rank,file) for file in range(n)}
    for file in range(n):
        prim["F%d"%file] = {"R%dF%d"%(rank,file) for rank in range(n)}
    return prim

def makeSecondary(n):
    # One secondary column for each diagonal
    second = dict()
    for s in range(2*n-1):
        second["S%d"%s] = {"R%dF%d"%(r, s-r) for r in range(max(0,s-n+1), min(s+1,n))}
    for d in range(-n+1, n):
        second["D%d"%(-d)]={"R%dF%d"%(r, r+d) for r in range(max(0,-d),min(n-d, n))}
    return second

rows = makeRows(n)
primary = makePrimary(n)
secondary = makeSecondary(n)
primary.update(secondary)
secondary = secondary.keys()
#for soln in solve(primary, rows, secondary, 15):
    #print(soln)
solutions = [s for s in solve(primary, rows, secondary)]
try:
    assert len(solutions) == solutionCounts[n]
except AssertionError:
    print("actual %d expected %d"%(len(solutions), solutionCounts[n]))
for soln in solutions:print(soln)
```

The code is set up to generate the first 6 solutions to the 5 queens problem, and it works fine.  (See the call

```
solutions = [s for s in solve(primary, rows, secondary, 6)]
```

at line 80.)  There are actually 10 solutions, and if I ask for 10 solutions, I get them all.   If I leave off the limit, so that the call is

```
solutions = [s for s in solve(primary, rows, secondary)]
```

the main program prints ten empty lists `[]` as the solutions, but the code in `solve` prints the real solutions.  The same thing happens if I make the limit 15.

The problem seems to arise when I convert the generator to a list in line 80.  If I put back the commented-out lines at lines 78 and 79, and comment out everything from line 80 on, the program works as I expect.  But I don't understand this; I've often made a list of the objects returned by a generator in this way.

Another thing that's even stranger is that, if I change line 13 to read

```
yield list(solution)
```

then the code from line 80 on works fine in all cases.  I can't remember how I stumbled on this kludge when I originally wrote the code.  I was looking at it today, and changed `yield list(solution)` to `yield solution` and that's when the bug became apparent.  I can't understand this; `solution` is already a list.  In fact, I've tried adding the line

```
assert solution == list(solution)
```

just before line 13 and it never raises `AssertionError`.

I'm at a complete loss.  I've tried to make a smaller script that will reproduce this behavior, but I haven't been able to.  Do you understand what's going on, and (harder) can you explain it to me?

Comment: Could be another case of [“Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: See [What is the pythonic way to avoid default parameters that are empty lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366422/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-avoid-default-parameters-that-are-empty-lists)

Comment: Nope. The default argument doesn't seem to be the case in this code

Comment: @iBug Yes, I don't see how it could be.  I'll change it, just to be sure, but I'm not optimistic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
yield solution
```

The problem is you're yielding a list which you subsequently add and remove items from. By the time the caller examines the list it has changed. You need to return frozen copies of the solution to ensure the results at the point of each `yield` statement are preserved. Any one of these will do:

```
yield list(solution)
yield solution[:]
yield tuple(solution)
```

Answer (score 4):

Prediction before seeing the code: `yield list(solution)` yields a shallow *copy* of solution.  `yield solution` yields the solution list *itself*, so when you mutate that list afterwards, you get into trouble.

---

And it looks like I'm right. :-)  Shorter version:

```
def weird(solution):
    for i in range(len(solution)):
        yield solution
        solution.pop()
```

which gives:

```
In [8]: result = list(weird(['a','b','c']))

In [9]: result
Out[9]: [[], [], []]
```

because

```
In [10]: [id(x) for x in result]
Out[10]: [140436644005128, 140436644005128, 140436644005128]
```

but if we `yield list(solution)` instead, we get

```
In [15]: list(less_weird(['a','b','c']))
Out[15]: [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b'], ['a']]
```

---

First we see one of your mutable default arguments, which is a bad idea, but not actually the cause of the bug you see:

```
def solver(Cols, Rows, SecondaryIDs, solution=[]):
    live=[col for col in Cols if col not in SecondaryIDs] 
    if not live:
        yield solution
```

Here you yield the solution ^..

```
else:
    col = min(live, key = lambda col: len(Cols[col]))        
    for row in list(Cols[col]):                                          
        solution.append(row)                                            
        columns = select(Cols, Rows, row)                        
        for soln in solver(Cols, Rows, SecondaryIDs, solution):
            yield soln
        deselect(Cols, Rows, row, columns)
        solution.pop()
```

And here you mutate *the same list you yielded beforehand*.