# Python argument values

Tags: python, variables

I am following the Python [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values).

```
def f(a, L=[]):
    L.append(a)
    return L
```

When I call `f`

```
print(f(1))
print(f(2))
print(f(3, L=[]))
print(f(4))
```

I get

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[3]
[1, 2, 4]
```

Why it returns `[1, 2, 4]` after `[3]` instead of `[3, 4]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you declare L=[] in the arguments. This creates the List that is assigned to L only once. For the third case where you have

```
print(f(3, L=[]))
```

you pass an empty list to the function for the parameter L. This does not overwrite L but is only valid for that specific function call. For the next call, it takes the default argument list again, which contains at that point in time [1,2].

It is (as far as I know) not possible to reassign the default parameter after initialization.

[This question may also be of interest to you as it talks about mutable default arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366422/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-avoid-default-parameters-that-are-empty-lists)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the same result you need to initialize a list and pass it to the function.

```
def f(a, L):
    L.append(a)
    return L
        
L = []
print(f(1, L))
print(f(2, L))
L = []
print(f(3, L))
print(f(4, L))
```

The output is

```
[1]                                                                                                                                                                                
[1, 2]                                                                                                                                                                             
[3]                                                                                                                                                                                
[3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a different value because of `L=[]` default value and it is mutable. The tutorial link you provided there clearly stated that

- Default value is evaluated only once
- the default is a mutable object such as a list, dictionary, or instances of most classes

So, When you pass another `L=[]` in your `f()` function then `L=[]` is initiating for a new one and return a single result. But after calling `f(4)` it's getting to default function and return update result

```
   def f(a, L=[]):
        L.append(a)
        return L
    
    print(f(1))
    print(f(2))
    print(f(3, L=[]))
    print(f(4))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still do not understand why it returns [3] and then [1, 2, 4]. Could you be more didactic please?

Comment: @Gui well assume you have to make `sum` the value of  `a` if it is `5` else print the value that is not 5. Now compare with `f(a, L=[])` where `L=[]` default. If the condition meets then it will append to `L=[]` list or print the value that comes from the user end.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that you are creating a new list object in memory by resetting a new value object of `L` at the third time it runs, so it stores the the `a` variable value in the new list object instead of appending to the old one that has been in memory already, but in step four and since `L=[]` has hasn't been changed this time it still points to the same old list object in memory, so step 4 `a` variable value gets stored there as well as step one and two.

here is a simple example:
if we modified the code a little bit to debug what's happening here, you will see that the `L` variable get's assigned to a new list object in memory at step 3.

```
def f(a, L=[]):
    L.append(a)
    print(f'Your function list id: {id(L)}, now gets assigned a value of: {a}')
    return L


print(f(1))
print(f(2))
print(f(3, L=[]))
print(f(4))
```