# I am getting this error ValueError: 0 is not in list

Tags: python, list, function

ValueError: 0 is not in list

I want to print the indices of `nums[x]` and `nums[y]` from the following code. But I am getting an error, *ValueError: 0 is not in list.*  Please, help me out. Thanks.

```
def twoSum(nums = [], target = 0):
  if len(nums) > 0:
    for x in range(len(nums)):
      for y in range(len(nums)):
        l = nums[x] + nums[y]
      if l == target:
        print(nums.index(x), nums.index(y))

twoSum(nums = [2,6,5], target = 7)
```

Comment: Don't use an [empty list as a default parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366422/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-avoid-default-parameters-that-are-empty-lists).

Answer (score 2):

```
print(nums[x], nums[y])
```

or if you want to get index then:

```
print(x, y)
```

You considering each number of list twice(Which is wrong)

```
for x in range(len(nums)-1):
      for y in range(1,len(nums)):
```