# Why does optional parameter act like global in recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion

I wrote a simple recursive program to get the Nth Fibonacci number with a cache to speed it up.

```
def fibonacci(n, cache={0:0, 1:1}):
    if n-1 not in cache:
        cache[n-1] = fibonacci(n-1)
    return cache[n-1] + cache[n-2]
```

The problem with that code is that I forgot to pass the cache variable into the recursive call, so I wouldn't expect it to work, since I can't access cache[n-2] once n > 3 -- however, it *does work* just the same as the the following correct example:

```
def fibonacci(n, cache={0:0, 1:1}):
    if n-1 not in cache:
        cache[n-1] = fibonacci(n-1, cache)
    return cache[n-1] + cache[n-2]
```

Can someone explain to me why it seems like cache is being passed into the recursive call in the first snippet?

Comment: Maybe it's related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366422/what-is-the-pythonic-way-to-avoid-default-parameters-that-are-empty-lists. In particular, the default parameter (here the mutable dict `{0:0, 1:1}`) is created when the function is created. So subsequent calls without `cache` will access this very object.

Comment: Try checking the memory address of `cache` for each recursive call

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are providing a *default* value for one of your function arguments (cache=default_argument). When you call `fibonacci` and provide a value for cache, then the value you pass in will be used. If you do not provide a value, then the default value is used.

Furthermore, the default argument is evaluated *once*, when the function is created. Therefore, the same cache object is being reused between invocations, and that is why it appears as if it is "global".