Robot framework passes arguments as a String but not the actual type (List, Dict, ...)
My test in robot looks like below
${filter} =  Create Filter with apps ${appList}

I've already declared the variable appList in my yaml file and loaded it in my test file.
Now I've my keyword file like below
Create Filter with apps ${list}
    ${app_filter} =  Generate app filters    ${list}

Generate app filter is my Python function which is as below
def generate_app_filters(appList=[]):
    for app in appList:
        print(app)

With this setup, when I have ${appList} value as ["app1", "app2"] in my variable yaml, it should be read as 2 separate apps in the python function generate_app_filter. My expected output should be like below
app1
app2

But my actual output is like this
[
"
a
p
p
1
"
,

"
a
p
p
2
"
]

I'm facing an issue where the generate_app_filters receives the argument as a string. Like"['app1', 'app2']" but not ['app1', 'app2']. Because of this, my Python function reads every character as a list element but not how I wanted it.
Am I doing anything wrong with the config?

There is a comment for another issue in your code. Using function's argument initialization like appList=[] could lead to a known problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366422/how-can-i-avoid-issues-caused-by-pythons-early-bound-default-parameters-e-g-m

You need to pass the variable as a list argument, eg @{} and not as ${}

http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#list-variable-syntax

I modified your Python definition (test.py) little bit:
def generate_app_filters(appList):
    result_list = []
    for app in appList:
        result_list.append(app)
    return  result_list

and here is the Robot code:
*** Test Cases ***
Verify that list is displayed
    ${filter} =       Create Filter with apps    ${my_App_list}
    Log To Console    First item of the list is ${filter}[0]
    Log To Console    Second item of the list is ${filter}[1]

*** Keywords ***
Create Filter with apps
    [Arguments]            ${LIST}
    ${myfilter} =          test.Generate App Filters    ${LIST} #'test' is the custom library definition
    Return From Keyword    ${myfilter}

The output of this setup is:
First  item of the list is app1
Second item of the list is app2  

Hope this helps.
