# Passing functions with arguments to another function in Python?

Tags: python, function

Is it possible to pass functions with arguments to another function in Python?

Say for something like:

```
def perform(function):
    return function()
```

But the functions to be passed will have arguments like:

```
action1()
action2(p)
action3(p,r)
```

Comment: It's not clear what the original requirements were here. If `perform` is supposed to contain logic that figures out the arguments and uses them to call `function` (including, for example, by receiving those arguments as additional parameters, as in the accepted answer), then [Python function as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289646) is a better version of the question.

Comment: On the other hand, if `perform` is expected to be able to call its passed-in `function` without arguments, then arguments for the underlying `action2` and `action3` need to be bound ahead of time - in which case the question is **really** about how to do that binding. [Python Argument Binders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277922/python-argument-binders) is the canonical for that.

Answer (score 370, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
def perform(fun, *args):
    fun(*args)

def action1(args):
    # something

def action2(args):
    # something

perform(action1)
perform(action2, p)
perform(action3, p, r)
```

Comment: What about named parameters? That is, `def action1(arg1, arg2=None, arg3=None)`, how could you pass an argument that you intend to be assigned to arg3, for instance?

Comment: perform( fun, **args ), see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954746/python-arguments-as-a-dictionary

Comment: What if `perform` and `action1`, `action2` on different files? @S.Lott

Comment: @alper _import_ them

Comment: Better with both positional and named args:
`def f(g, *args, **kwargs): g(*args, **kwargs)`

Comment: **To do this in C++** using [variadic templates and parameter packs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack), see my code example from my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo here: [variadic_templates_parameter_packs_and_functions.cpp](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/cpp/variadic_templates_parameter_packs_and_functions.cpp)

Comment: I don't see a Q&A already covering this for the C++ case, so I've added a Q&A on it here: [How can I pass a function name and variable list of arguments to a function in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73904873/4561887)

Answer (score 186):

This is what lambda is for:

```
def perform(f):
    f()

perform(lambda: action1())
perform(lambda: action2(p))
perform(lambda: action3(p, r))
```

Comment: Also out of curiosity, can you please tell me why lambdas are not good for this case?

Comment: lambdas are one of the best features of good programming languages.  unfortunately, Python's implementation is severely limited.  in this case, however, they fit perfectly

Comment: I find that the limited syntax is nearly opaque; they're hard to explain to n00bz.  Yes, they do work here, and the confusing features of the syntax are absent.  This is -- perhaps -- the only example I've seen of a lambda that's not obscure.

Comment: So that you could retrieve the passed function's result, wouldn't it be better if Perform() called "return f()" rather than just calling f().

Comment: I think that the lambda version is quite neat, but oddly in tests I ran it was slower to call functions via the lambda than by the fn(*args) method discussed in another answer.

Comment: wonderful!! exactly what I needed in order to pass parametrized chained functions to other functions.

Comment: I see that a defined function can be passed, but is it possible to save the return value in a variable? say something like, `ex = perform(lambda: action1())` I've tried it, but the value is always `None`.

Answer (score 55):

You can use the partial function from functools like so.

```
from functools import partial

def perform(f):
    f()

perform(Action1)
perform(partial(Action2, p))
perform(partial(Action3, p, r))
```

Also works with keywords

```
perform(partial(Action4, param1=p))
```

Comment: `functools.partial` is also more versatile if `perform` needs to hand over further parameters to `f`. E.g., one could call `perform(partial(Action3, p))` and `perform(f)` could do something like `f("this is parameter r")`.

Answer (score 16):

Use functools.partial, not lambdas! And ofc Perform is a useless function, you can pass around functions directly.

```
for func in [Action1, partial(Action2, p), partial(Action3, p, r)]:
  func()
```

Comment: It depends on whether you want the arguments to be evaluated at the call site of Perform or not.

Comment: @Dave: no it doesn't depends. Provided arguments to partial are always evaluated when calling partial, never at "perform" function.

Answer (score 14):

This is called partial functions and there are at least 3 ways to do this. My favorite way is using lambda because it avoids dependency on extra package and is the least verbose. Assume you have a function `add(x, y)` and you want to pass `add(3, y)` to some other function as parameter such that the other function decides the value for `y`.

**Use lambda**

```
# generic function takes op and its argument
def runOp(op, val):
    return op(val)

# declare full function
def add(x, y):
    return x+y

# run example
def main():
    f = lambda y: add(3, y)
    result = runOp(f, 1) # is 4
```

**Create Your Own Wrapper**

Here you need to create a function that returns the partial function. This is obviously lot more verbose.

```
# generic function takes op and its argument
def runOp(op, val):
    return op(val)

# declare full function
def add(x, y):
    return x+y

# declare partial function
def addPartial(x):
    def _wrapper(y):
        return add(x, y)
    return _wrapper

# run example
def main():
    f = addPartial(3)
    result = runOp(f, 1) # is 4
```

**Use partial from functools**

This is almost identical to `lambda` shown above. Then why do we need this? There are [few reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252228/python-why-is-functools-partial-necessary/). In short, `partial` might be bit faster in some cases (see its [implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)) and that you can use it for early binding vs lambda's late binding.

```
from functools import partial

# generic function takes op and its argument
def runOp(op, val):
    return op(val)

# declare full function
def add(x, y):
    return x+y

# run example
def main():
    f = partial(add, 3)
    result = runOp(f, 1) # is 4
```

Comment: Another (fourth) possible method would be to create a class and make it support `__call__` it can be useful in some bizarre cases like if the final function parameters may be provided asynchronously to the callable context (rather rare), the 3 methods above are much more common.

Answer (score 5):

(months later) a tiny real example where lambda is useful, partial not:
say you want various 1-dimensional cross-sections through a 2-dimensional function,
like slices through a row of hills.
`quadf( x, f )` takes a 1-d `f` and calls it for various `x`.
To call it for vertical cuts at y = -1 0 1 and horizontal cuts at x = -1 0 1,

```
fx1 = quadf( x, lambda x: f( x, 1 ))
fx0 = quadf( x, lambda x: f( x, 0 ))
fx_1 = quadf( x, lambda x: f( x, -1 ))
fxy = parabola( y, fx_1, fx0, fx1 )

f_1y = quadf( y, lambda y: f( -1, y ))
f0y = quadf( y, lambda y: f( 0, y ))
f1y = quadf( y, lambda y: f( 1, y ))
fyx = parabola( x, f_1y, f0y, f1y )
```

As far as I know, `partial` can't do this --

```
quadf( y, partial( f, x=1 ))
TypeError: f() got multiple values for keyword argument 'x'
```

(How to add tags numpy, partial, lambda to this ?)

Comment: If you had this problem, it is something specific to the `f` that you wanted to use, which isn't shown here - so there's no way anyone else could debug the problem. That would be a separate question, anyway. While this is over a decade old, this seems like an appropriate place for a reminder that Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum**.

Answer (score 2):

Although all the responses are very accurate and well explained.
I want to make a clarification that you also can pass **anonymous functions**.

```py
def perform(fun, *arg):
    return fun(*arg)

# Pass anonymous function
print(perform(lambda x: x + 1, 3)) # output: 4
print(perform(lambda x, y: x + y + 1, 3, 2)) # output: 6

# Pass defined function
perform(lambda: action1())
perform(lambda: action2(p))
perform(lambda: action3(p, r))
```

Comment: I see you can pass a defined function, but is it possible to save the return value into a variable? I've attempted this, but the value is always `None`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it with a closure:

```
    def generate_add_mult_func(func):
        def function_generator(x):
            return reduce(func,range(1,x))
        return function_generator

    def add(x,y):
        return x+y

    def mult(x,y):
        return x*y

    adding=generate_add_mult_func(add)
    multiplying=generate_add_mult_func(mult)

    print adding(10)
    print multiplying(10)
```

Comment: In any case one needs to do more than just passing a function to another one closure is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for...

```
def action1(action):
    print(f'doing {action} here!')

def perform(function):
    return function()

perform(lambda : action1('business action'))
```

`lambda` packages up func and args in closure and passes to `perform()`

Thanks to David Beasley.