# Python: Why is functools.partial necessary?

Tags: python, functional-programming, partial-application

Partial application is cool. What functionality does [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) offer that you can't get through lambdas?

```
>>> sum = lambda x, y : x + y
>>> sum(1, 2)
3
>>> incr = lambda y : sum(1, y)
>>> incr(2)
3
>>> def sum2(x, y):
    return x + y

>>> incr2 = functools.partial(sum2, 1)
>>> incr2(4)
5
```

Is `functools` somehow more efficient, or readable?

Answer (score 319):

> What functionality does `functools.partial` offer that you can't get through lambdas?

Not much in terms of extra *functionality* (but, see later) – and, readability is in the eye of the beholder.
Most people who are familiar with functional programming languages (those in the Lisp/Scheme families in particular) appear to like `lambda` just fine – I say "most", definitely *not* all, because Guido and I assuredly are among those "familiar with" (etc) yet think of `lambda` as an eyesore anomaly in Python...
He was repentant of ever having accepted it into Python whereas planned to remove it from Python 3, as one of "Python's glitches".
I fully supported him in that.  (I love `lambda` *in Scheme*... while its limitations *in Python*, and the weird way it *just doesn't fit in* with the rest of the language, make my skin crawl).

Not so, however, for the hordes of `lambda` lovers -- who staged one of the closest things to a rebellion ever seen in Python's history, until Guido backtracked and decided to leave `lambda` in.
Several possible additions to `functools` (to make functions returning constants, identity, etc) didn't happen (to avoid explicitly duplicating more of `lambda`'s functionality), though `partial` did of course remain (it's no *total* duplication, nor is it an eyesore).

Remember that `lambda`'s body is limited to be an *expression*, so it's got limitations.  For example...:

```
>>> import functools
>>> f = functools.partial(int, base=2)
>>> f.args
()
>>> f.func
<type 'int'>
>>> f.keywords
{'base': 2}
>>>
```

`functools.partial`'s returned function is decorated with attributes useful for introspection -- the function it's wrapping, and what positional and named arguments it fixes therein.  Further, the named arguments can be overridden right back (the "fixing" is rather, in a sense, the setting of defaults):

```
>>> f('23', base=10)
23
```

So, as you see, it's *definely* not as simplistic as `lambda s: int(s, base=2)`!-)

Yes, you *could* contort your lambda to give you some of this – e.g., for the keyword-overriding,

```
>>> f = lambda s, **k: int(s, **dict({'base': 2}, **k))
```

but I dearly **hope** that even the most ardent `lambda`-lover doesn't consider *this* horror more readable than the `partial` call!-). The "attribute setting" part is even harder, because of the "body's a single expression" limitation of Python's `lambda` (plus the fact that assignment can never be part of a Python expression)... you end up "faking assignments within an expression" by stretching list comprehension well beyond its design limits...:

```
>>> f = [f for f in (lambda f: int(s, base=2),)
           if setattr(f, 'keywords', {'base': 2}) is None][0]
```

Now combine the named-arguments overridability, plus the setting of three attributes, into a single expression, and tell me just how readable *that* is going to be...!

Comment: Yeah, I'd say that the extra functionality of `functools.partial` that you mentioned makes it superior to lambda. Perhaps this is the topic of another post, but what is it on a design level that bothers you so much about `lambda`?

Comment: @Rosarch, as I said: first, it limitations (Python sharply distinguishes expressions and statements -- there's much you can't do, or can't do _sensibly_, within a single expression, and that's what a lambda's body _is_); second, its absolutely weird syntax sugar. If I could go back in time and change one thing within Python, it would be the absurd, meaningless, eyesore `def` and `lambda` keywords: make them both `function` (one name choice Javascript got _really_ right), and at least 1/3 of my objections would vanish!-).  As I said, I have no objection to lambda _in Lisp_...!-)

Comment: @Alex Martelli, Why did Guido set such a limitation for lambda: "body's a single expression" ? C#'s lambda body could be anything valid in a function's body. Why don't Guido just remove the limitation for python lambda?

Comment: @PeterLong Hopefully [Guido](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=147358) can answer your question. The gist of it is that it would be too complex, and that you can use a `def` anyway. Our benevolent leader has spoken!

Comment: @AlexMartelli DropBox has had an interesting influence on Guido - https://twitter.com/gvanrossum/status/391769557758521345

Comment: Readability is **partially** in the eye of the beholder. It has objective components - like the number of eye saccades it takes to see all the details, how much visual detail you have to resolve before you can confidently know what you are looking at, and so on. Even the eye-of-the-beholder stuff is often relativistic but still varies along predictable objective principles (visual acuity, distance to screen, how much code fits on screen, the brain getting habitualized to expect and parse specific patterns visual acuity, etc), not just randomly different as arbitrary matters of taste.

Comment: +1 but convoluted lambda example detracts from the answer: lambdas can have default arguments too: `f = lambda s, base=2: int(s, base=base)`.

Answer (score 106):

Well, here's an example that shows a difference:

```
In [132]: sum = lambda x, y: x + y

In [133]: n = 5

In [134]: incr = lambda y: sum(n, y)

In [135]: incr2 = partial(sum, n)

In [136]: print incr(3), incr2(3)
8 8

In [137]: n = 9

In [138]: print incr(3), incr2(3)
12 8
```

These posts by Ivan Moore expand on the "limitations of lambda" and closures in python:

- [Closures in Python (part 2)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150516040133/http://ivan.truemesh.com/archives/000411.html)
- [Closures in Python (part 3)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150512214024/http://ivan.truemesh.com/archives/000425.html)

Comment: Good example. To me, this seems more a "bug" with lambda, actually, but I understand others may disagree. (Something similar happens with closures defined within a loop, as implemented in several programming languages.)

Comment: The fix to this "early vs late binding dilemma" is to explicitly use early binding, when you want that, by `lambda y, n=n: ...`.  Late binding (of names appearing _only_ in a function's body, not in its `def` or equivalent `lambda`) is anything **but** a bug, as I've shown at length in long SO answers in the past: you early-bind explicitly when that's what you want, use the late-binding default when *that* is what you want, and that's _exactly_ the right design choice given the context of the rest of Python's design.

Comment: @Alex Martelli: Yeah, sorry. I just fail to get used to late binding properly, perhaps because I think when defining functions that I'm actually defining something for good, and the unexpected surprises only cause me headaches. (More when I try to do functional things in Javascript than in Python, though.) I understand that many people *are* comfortable with late binding, and that it's consistent with the rest of Python's design. I would still like to read your other long SO answers, though -- links? :-)

Comment: Alex is right, it's not a bug.  But it's a "gotcha" that traps many lambda enthusiasts.  For the "bug" side of the argument from a haskel/functional type, see Andrej Bauer's post: http://math.andrej.com/2009/04/09/pythons-lambda-is-broken/

Comment: @ars: Ah yes, thanks for the link to Andrej Bauer's post. Yeah, the effects of late binding are certainly something that we mathematics-types (worse, with a Haskell background) keep finding grossly unexpected and shocking. :-) I'm not sure I'd go as far as Prof. Bauer and call it a design error, but it *is* hard for human programmers to completely switch between one way of thinking and another. (Or perhaps this is just my insufficient Python experience.)

Comment: BTW, this issue (here and in Andrej Bauer's post) is a good reason to remove lambda from Python: it doesn't do the sensible thing that many would expect. ;-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, too late to remove anything -- Python 3 is way finalized (wait another 20 years for Python 4;-).  Re some of my answers above mentioned, "let me google it for you": http://www.google.com/search?q=%2Bearly+%2Blate+%2Bbinding+%2B"alex+martelli"+site:stackoverflow.com (I don't know how to do the equivalent search on SO directly, but this one has at least some relevant ones, it seems).

Comment: Can you explain with words what lambdas are doing "wrong" in the question example? Just looking the code is not easy to get how it is happening and going wrong. After looking, it seems that lambdas do not "copy" the parameters values, and they use it from the current context, while `partial` does "copy" the values on the moment of creation. Meaming lambdas have a dynamic context, while `partial` has a fixed one for the function parameter's variables used.

Comment: Beware, the linked articles "Closures in Python" were written in 2004, things have probably evolved a lot since then.

Answer (score 30):

In the latest versions of Python (>=2.7), you can `pickle` a `partial`, but not a `lambda`:

```
>>> pickle.dumps(partial(int))
'cfunctools\npartial\np0\n(c__builtin__\nint\np1\ntp2\nRp3\n(g1\n(tNNtp4\nb.'
>>> pickle.dumps(lambda x: int(x))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-11-e32d5a050739>", line 1, in <module>
    pickle.dumps(lambda x: int(x))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1374, in dumps
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 748, in save_global
    (obj, module, name))
PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x1729aa0>: it's not found as __main__.<lambda>
```

Comment: Unfortunately partial functions fail to pickle for `multiprocessing.Pool.map()`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3637905/195139

Comment: @wting That post is from 2010. `partial` is pickleable in Python 2.7.

Comment: You can *pickle* lambdas with `dill`

Answer (score 27):

> Is functools somehow more efficient..?

As a partly answer to this I decided to test the performance. Here is my example:

```
from functools import partial
import time, math

def make_lambda():
    x = 1.3
    return lambda: math.sin(x)

def make_partial():
    x = 1.3
    return partial(math.sin, x)

Iter = 10**7

start = time.clock()
for i in range(0, Iter):
    l = make_lambda()
stop = time.clock()
print('lambda creation time {}'.format(stop - start))

start = time.clock()
for i in range(0, Iter):
    l()
stop = time.clock()
print('lambda execution time {}'.format(stop - start))

start = time.clock()
for i in range(0, Iter):
    p = make_partial()
stop = time.clock()
print('partial creation time {}'.format(stop - start))

start = time.clock()
for i in range(0, Iter):
    p()
stop = time.clock()
print('partial execution time {}'.format(stop - start))
```

on Python 3.3 it gives:

```
lambda creation time 3.1743163756961392
lambda execution time 3.040552701787919
partial creation time 3.514482823352731
partial execution time 1.7113973411608114
```

Which means that partial needs a bit more time for creation but considerably less time for execution. This can well be the effect of the early and late binding which are discussed in the answer from [ars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3252364/1536976).

Comment: More importantly, `partial` is written in C, rather than pure Python, meaning it can produce a more efficient callable than simply creating a function that calls another function.

Comment: Note that partials still have an overhead compared to handing the arguments over explicitly. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388438/python-functools-partial-efficiency

Answer (score 13):

Besides the extra functionality Alex mentioned, another advantage of functools.partial is speed. With partial you can avoid constructing (and destructing) another stack frame.

Neither the function generated by partial nor lambdas have docstrings by default (though you can set the doc string for any objects via `__doc__`).

You can find more details in this blog: [Partial Function Application in Python](http://web.archive.org/web/20150316142332/http://tech.pro/tutorial/1520/partial-function-application-in-python)

Comment: If you have tested the speed advantage, what speed improvement of partial over lambda can be expected?

Comment: When you say that the docstring is inherited, which Python version do you refer to? In Python 2.7.15 and Python 3.7.2 they are not inherited. Which is a good thing, because the original docstring is not necessarily correct for the function with partially applied arguments.

Comment: For python 2.7 (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#partial-objects): "the __name__ and __doc__ attributes are not created automatically". Same for 3.[5-7].

Comment: There is a mistake in your link: log_info = partial(log_template, level="info") - it's not possible because level is not a keyword argument in the example. Both python 2 and 3 say: "TypeError: log_template() got multiple values for argument 'level'".

Comment: In fact, I created a partial(f) by hand and it gives __doc__ field as 'partial(func, *args, **keywords) - new function with partial application\n    of the given arguments and keywords.\n' (both for python 2 and 3).

Answer (score 1):

I understand the intent quickest in the third example.

When I parse lambdas, I'm expecting more complexity/oddity than offered by the standard library directly.

Also, you'll notice that the third example is the only one which doesn't depend on the full signature of `sum2`; thus making it slightly more loosely coupled.

Comment: Hm, I'm actually of the opposite persuasion, I took a lot longer to parse the `functools.partial` call, whereas the lambdas are self-evident.

Answer (score 1):

Super old question, but I thought I'd drop this here in case it's useful to someone.

One advantage of partials over lambda is in how they behave in loops. Due to the way lambda evaluate parameters an easy way to get tripped up in using them is when declaring lambda functions as part of a loop (e.g. callback methods for menu items).

For example, this gives you an answer that developers unfamiliar with this behaviour in lambdas might be surprised by,

```
funcs = []
for i in range(10):
    f = lambda j: i + j
    funcs.append(f)
print(f(1) for f in funcs)
# [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
```

However, if you use partials, you don't have this problem;

```
parts = []
for i in range(10):
    p = partial(sum, (i, ))
    parts.append(p)
print([p(1) for p in parts])
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Of course, there are [ways around the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837486/lambda-in-a-loop) with lambda, but with partials the syntax is (IMO) far more straightforward and behaves as you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

Functionals serve a useful purpose for when certain variables are evaluated.

Coming from an outsider, here's a series of more friendly examples:

```py
from functools import partial

sum = lambda x, y: x + y            # sum(x, y) == x + y

n = 2
normalSum = lambda x: sum(x, n)     # normalSum(x) == sum(x, y=n)
partialSum = partial(sum, y = n)    # partialSum(sum(y=n)) == sum(x, 2)
print(normalSum(2), partialSum(2))  # 4 4

n = 6
print(normalSum(2), partialSum(2))  # 8 4
```

Notice how the partial holds the value of whatever was `n` at the time.

```py
...
n = 2
partialSumOrig = partial(sum, y = n)        # partialSumOrig(sum(y=n)) == sum(x, 2)
n = 6
partialSumNew = partial(sum, y = n)         # partialSumNew(sum(y=n)) == sum(x, 6)

print(partialSumOrig(2), partialSumNew(2))  # 4 8
```

Extra example showing how arguments are passed into nested lambdas:

```py
...
n = 8
partialSumOrig = partial(sum, y = n)  # partialSumOrig(sum(y=n)) == sum(x, 8)
partialSumNew = partial(sum, n)       # partialSumNew(sum(n)) == sum(8, y)

print(partialSumOrig(2))  # 10        # partialSumOrig(sum(2, 8)) == sum(2, 8)
print(partialSumNew(2))   # 10        # partialSumNew(sum(8, 2)) == sum(8, 2)
```

One last example showing how arguments are passed in partials:

```py
...
n = 2
m = 2
partialSumSilly = partial(sum, n, m)  # partialSumSilly(sum(n, m)) == sum(2, 2)
print(partialSumSilly())              # 4
```

The big takeaway is that:

- `normalSum()` *behaves* like a late binding, where `n` is evaluated when ran.
- `partialSum()` *behaves* like an early binding, where `n` is evaluated when defined.

Note: In reality *nearly everything* is a late binding in cpython due to its interpreted nature.