# How to find an index of an item in a list, searching the item with a regular expression in Python?

Tags: python, regex, list, indexing

I have a list like that:

```
lst = ['something', 'foo1', 'bar1', 'blabla', 'foo2']
```

Is it possible to get the index of the first item starting with "foo" (foo1) using regular expressions and `lst.index()` like:

```
ind = lst.index("some_regex_for_the_item_starting_with_foo") ?
```

I know I can create a counter and a for loop and use method `startswith()`.
I am curious if I miss some shorter and more elegant way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that it's ok and you can use startswith method if it do what you really want(i am not sure that you really need regEx here - however code below can be easily modified to use regEx):

```
data = ['text', 'foo2', 'foo1', 'sample']
indeces = (i for i,val in enumerate(data) if val.startswith('foo'))
```

Or with regex:

```
from re import match
data = ['text', 'foo2', 'foo1', 'sample']
indeces = (i for i,val in enumerate(data) if match('foo', val))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do it using the `lst.index`, however here is an alternative method that you may find more elegant than a for loop:

```
try:
    ind = (i for i, v in enumerate(lst) if v.startswith("foo")).next()
except StopIteration:
    ind = -1   # or however you want to say that the item wasn't found
```

As senderle pointed out in a comment, this can be shortened by using the `next()` built-in function (2.6+) with a default value to shorten this to one line:

```
ind = next((i for i, v in enumerate(lst) if v.startswith("foo")), -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately there is no `key` parameter for `list.index`.
Having that a solution could have been

```
# warning: NOT working code
result = L.index(True, key=lambda x: regexp.match(x) is not None)
```

Moreover given that I just discovered that `lambda` apparently is considered in the python community an abomination I'm not sure if more `key` parameters are going to be added in the future.

Comment: Don't you think `key` is useful without lambda? With `operator.itemgetter` for example? I'm also curious who thinks `lambda` is an abomination. It can be really ugly, sure, but it's an important part of the language I think, especially when you have a built-in function that doesn't do _quite_ what you want.

Comment: @senderle: yes `key` can be useful with other cases but in many common cases using a small anonymous closure is just perfect for `key`. About why `lambda` is so hated I just discovered this recently (at EuroPython) where I was asking why in an example `function.Partial` had been used in a case that should have been a job for `lambda` and Alex Martelli replied <<The only reasonable phrase which contains both 'lambda' and 'should' is 'lambda should be removed from Python'>>. See for a longer explanation http://stackoverflow.com/q/3252228/320726

Comment: thanks, that clears things up for me.  I think this is a case where (for me), practicality beats purity. I see AM's side of things, though; I guess I wouldn't cry (too hard) if `lambda` were removed.

Answer (score 0):

It would be kind of cool to have something like this built in. Python doesn't though. There are a few interesting solutions using itertools. (These also made me wish for a `itertools.takewhile_false`. If it existed, these would be more readable.)

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> import re
>>> m = re.compile('foo.*')
>>> print len(tuple(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: not m.match(x), lst)))
1
```

That was my first idea, but it requires you to create a temporary tuple and take its length. Then it occurred to me that you could just do a simple sum, and avoid the temporary list:

```
>>> print sum(1 for _ in takewhile(lambda x: not m.match(x), lst))
1
```

But that's also somewhat cumbersome. I prefer to avoid throw-away variables when possible. Let's try this again.

```
>>> sum(takewhile(bool, (not m.match(x) for x in lst)))
1
```

Much better.

Comment: Your solution is quite extraodinary and at the same time not quite readable, however I got what you did. I guess using "not" instead of using a function takewhile_false is more natural though. The same thing is if there was a while_false loop instead of "while smth != smth2"

Comment: I've found "dropwhile" in itertools. I guess this is just what you meant by "takewhile_false"

Comment: @rightaway717, no, `dropwhile` _discards_ items until the predicate is true, and then takes the rest, just as `takewhile` _takes_ items until the predicate is true and discards the rest. In other words, given the same iterable and predicate, `takewhile` will yield the first part of the list, and `dropwhile` will yield the second part of the list.

Comment: Sorry but this is terrible, you're building a tuple (potentially large) just to compute an index?

Comment: @alexis, well, that's why I improved on the first version, as you surely must have seen if you read the whole post. The later versions don't create tuples. I suppose it's possible that `sum` builds a tuple internally -- in which case I have to take issue with the implementation of `sum`.

Comment: @senderle: Sorry, I missed the part where you mention the tuple yourself. `takewhile` and `sum` wouldn't build a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = ['something', 'foo1', 'bar1', 'blabla', 'foo2']
l.index(filter(lambda x:x.startswith('foo'),l)[0])
```

Comment: I'll keep in mind this solution. I just started learning python and didnt know it means the same as "i for i,val in ...". Now I know that. Thank you for your efforts