# Python: using map() without lambdas on a multidimensional array/list

Tags: python, lambda, functional-programming

I have some code in python, that bitwise or-equals b to all the values in an a multidimensional list called a

```
for i in xrange(len(a)):
    for j in xrange(len(a[i])):
        a[i][j] |= b
```

My question is, is there any way to write this code using only (map(), filter(), reduce()) without having to use lambdas or any other function definitions like in the example below

```
map(lambda x: map(lambda y: y | b, x), a)
```

Comment: What is the use case for using the higher-order functions map, filter, and reduce without a function parameter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see absolutely no reason why one should ever avoid lambdas or list comprehensions, but here goes:

```
import operator,functools
a = map(functools.partial(map, functools.partial(operator.or_, b)), a)
```

Comment: Note that `functools.partial` is similar to `lambda`, so IMHO the correct answer is *No you can't*, as @senderle already wrote: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9561602/1763602 . About `functools.partial` vs `lambda`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3252425/1763602

Answer (score 4):

`map`, `filter`, and `reduce` all take functions (or at least callables -- i.e. anything with a `__call__` method) as arguments. So basically, no. You have to define a function, or a class.

Comment: ...or, to state the obvious, use a built-in function that is defined elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Python has no terse currying syntax, so you can't do something like `map(b |, x)`.

I would just use list comprehensions:

```
[y | b for x in a for y in x]
```