# Overriding queryset for inline admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

I'm having some trouble overriding the queryset for my inline admin.

Here's a bog-standard parent admin and inline admin:

```
class MyInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MyInlineModel
    def queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(MyInlineAdmin, self).queryset(request)
        return qs

class ParentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [MyInlineAdmin]
admin.site.register(ParentAdminModel, ParentAdmin)
```

Now I can do `qs.filter(user=request.user)` or `qs.filter(date__gte=datetime.today())` no problem.

But what I need is either the MyInlineModel instance or the ParentAdminModel instance (not the model!), as I need to filter my queryset based on that.

Is it possible to get something like self.instance or obj (like in get_readonly_fields() or get_formset()) inside the queryset() method?

Hope this makes sense. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950193/how-to-get-the-current-model-instance-from-inlineadmin-in-django might be helpful

Comment: Note that in Django 1.6 the queryset method was renamed to get_queryset. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/#get-query-set-and-similar-methods-renamed-to-get-queryset

Answer (score 8):

```
class MyInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MyInlineModel
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        """enable ordering drop-down alphabetically"""
        if db_field.name == 'car':
            kwargs['queryset'] = Car.objects.order_by("name") 
        return super(MyInlineAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

class ParentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [MyInlineAdmin]

admin.site.register(ParentAdminModel, ParentAdmin)
```

Im assuming your models look something like:

```
class MyInlineModel(models.Model):
    car=models.Foreignkey(Car)
    #blah
```

for more on this; read the django Docs on formfield_for_foreignkey-->
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey

Comment: This doesn't work at all. The `formfield_for_foreignkey` is for dropdown and similar widgets. See [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703652/limit-the-queryset-of-entries-displayed-for-a-django-admin-inline) instead.