# django admin dynamically set changeform initial data

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I'm implementing a m2m relationship through an intermediate model using the default m2m widget. I have the `Person` and `Project` models related using the `Membership` model.

So far I've succeeded at displaying the default m2m widget in the `Person` change form and creating the intermediate model instances correctly, but my problem is populating the widget when a `Person` is being modified.

This is the form class I'm using with the `PersonAdmin`:

```
class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm):
    projects = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(models.Project.objects.all(),
                                              widget=widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple(
                                                  verbose_name="Projects",
                                                  is_stacked=False,
                                                  attrs={'rows':'10'}))
    projects.required = False
    class Meta:
        model = models.Person
        fields = ['name', 'last_name', 'personal_id_number',
                  'personal_id_type', 'administrative_viability',
                  'observations']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        ret = super(PersonForm, self).save(commit)
        for p in self.cleaned_data['projects']:
            models.Membership.objects.create(person=self.instance, project=p)
        return ret
```

And the `PersonAdmin` itself:

```
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PersonForm

    def get_changeform_initial_data(self, request):
        initial = super(PersonAdmin, self).get_changeform_initial_data(request)
        initial['projects'] = models.Person.get(pk=initial['person']).project_set.all()
        return initial
```

I tried setting the initial value of `projects` in the method `get_changeform_initial_data` like that, but it doesn't work. Overall it looks like it's being ignored, as if I'm not overriding it properly.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950193/how-to-get-the-current-model-instance-from-inlineadmin-in-django) gave me the idea of overriding the `__init__` method of my `PersonForm`:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'instance' in kwargs:
        person = kwargs['instance']
        initial = {'projects': person.project_set.all()}
        kwargs['initial'] = initial
    super(PersonForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I still don't know why overriding `get_changeform_initial_data` wasn't working.

Answer (score 4):

`get_changeform_initial_data` is only called if it's *not* a change. I know this makes no sense. I suspect it's a bug.

See `django/contrib/admin/options.py` from line 1573, which is the only call to this method in the whole of Django:

```
            if add:
                initial = self.get_changeform_initial_data(request)
                form = ModelForm(initial=initial)
                formsets, inline_instances = self._create_formsets(request, form.instance, change=False)
            else:
                form = ModelForm(instance=obj)
                formsets, inline_instances = self._create_formsets(request, obj, change=True)
```

Update: [Looks like it's deliberate](https://github.com/django/django/commit/6acaa5238668593d6d854b28dbfa65e95796585c). I'll ask the developers why it works like this.