# How to bind a constant parameter in Python?

Tags: python

I have got a class similar to

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def noParam(self):
        return self.a
    def withParam(self, b)
        return self.a + b
instC = C(5.)
```

I need to pass a method of a particular instance of a class as a parameter. Passing `instC.noParam` works fine, but how do I pass `instC.withParam` with `b` always equal to say `239`? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to use [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
import functools

instC = C(5.)
meth = functools.partial(instC.withParam, 239)
```

Then you can pass this method (bound with both your instance and the value 239):

```
do_thing(meth)
```

Comment: This is the best approach, but would also be good to mention `lambda` -- it is both an alternative and also helps explain what `partial` is doing.

Comment: @Francis: why is this one better than lambda?

Comment: sorry should have googled first (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252228/python-why-is-functools-partial-necessary)

Comment: I prefer a lambda to `functools.partial` because a lambda is easier to debug.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `lambda` functions to bind parameters:

`meth = lambda: instC.withParam(239)`