# Issues with generating a defaultdict with a deque

Tags: python

I'd like to generate a defaultdict that contains a deque. For example:

```
d = defaultdict(deque)
```

The above work fine, but I'd like to make the deque a fixed length by passing in an argument:

```
d = defaultdict(deque(maxlen=10))
```

How can I pass arguments such as this to defaultdict?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use a partially applied function:

```
from functools import partial
defaultdict(partial(deque, maxlen=10))
```

Demo:

```
>>> deque10 = partial(deque, maxlen=10)
>>> deque10()
deque([], maxlen=10)
>>> deque10(range(20))
deque([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], maxlen=10)
```

See [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) docs for details.

Comment: Great thanks. I see `defaultdict(lambda: deque(maxlen=10))` also would work.

Comment: @turtle: yes, but it's not as pretty, IMHO. `partial` is considered more Pythonic than `lambda`.

Comment: `lambda` is certainly worth mentioning; but see this question and the answer by [Alex Martelli](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252228/python-why-is-functools-partial-necessary) for a wonderful explanation of the benefits of `partial` over `lambda`.

Comment: thanks, this is exactly the use case I was looking for. `partial` can be useful in many cases where you need pass uncalled function along with some arguments for it.