# Define a list of functions from a generic function

Tags: python, metaprogramming, decorator

Say I have a function

```
def my_meta_function (a, b, c):
  pass
```

I would like **define** an array of functions `myfunctions = [f1, f2, f3, ... f100]`, where the argument `c` is fixed to a different value for each such function, e.g. `c = [1,2,3, .. 100]`, and the functions only take the arguments `a` and `b`. In practice, the arguments I am considering are more complictated, but I am trying to understand how to do this in the language.

- Does this type of meta-programming have a name?
- Are **decorators** appropriate for this? If not, why?

Comment: Are the functions at all based on the arguments? Do you have the function objects already? Can you please provide more detail and a usecase?

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters I have updated the post. The new functions take the arguments `(a,b)`, leaving only `c` fixed. The body of the functions would be the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
>>> from functools import partial
def func(a, b, c):
...     print a, b, c
...     
>>> funcs = [partial(func, c=i) for i in xrange(5)]
>>> funcs[0](1, 2)
1 2 0
>>> funcs[1](1, 2)
1 2 1
>>> funcs[2](1, 2)
1 2 2
```

Just for learning purpose you can also do this using `lambda`:

```
>>> funcs = [lambda a, b, i=i:func(a, b, c=i) for i in xrange(5)]
>>> funcs[0](1, 2)
1 2 0
>>> funcs[1](1, 2)
1 2 1
```

But you should not use it, why?:

- [Python: Why is functools.partial necessary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252228/python-why-is-functools-partial-necessary)
- [What do (lambda) function closures capture in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture-in-python)

Comment: Thanks. For me to understand better how this relates to other metaprogramming features in Python. Do you know if this can be done with a decorator?

Comment: @Josh Yes you can implement this as a decorator, look at the docs of partial you'll find an example.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
>>> def func(c):
...    def wrapped(a, b):
...        return (a+b)*c
...    return wrapped
...
>>> funcs = [func(c+1) for c in xrange(100)]
>>> funcs[0](1, 2)
3
>>> funcs[1](1, 2)
6
```