# functools.partial vs normal Python function

Tags: python, lambda, partial-application

I am learning about partials and when to use them. In this page about [partials vs lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3252228/python-why-is-functools-partial-necessary), the accepted answer explains that one of the advantages of `partials` over `lambdas`, is that partials have attributes useful for introspection. So we can do the following with partials:

```
import functools
f = functools.partial(int, base=2)
print f.args, f.func, f.keywords

((), int, {'base': 2})
```

Indeed, we cannot do that with `lambdas`:

```
h = lambda x : int(x,base=2)
print h.args, h.func, h.keywords

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'args'
```

But actually, we cannot do that with "normal" Python functions either:

```
def g(x) :
  return int(x,base=2) 
print g.args, g.func, g.keywords

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'args'
```

Why do partials have more functionalities than normal Python functions? What is the intent of such a design? Is introspection considered useless for normal functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Functions *do* have information about what arguments they accept. The attribute names and data structures are aimed at the interpreter more than the developer, but the info *is* there. You'd have to introspect the `.func_defaults` and `.func_code.co_varnames` structures (and a few more besides) to find those details.

Using the [`inspect.getargspec()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec) makes extracting the info a little more straightforward:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> h = lambda x : int(x,base=2)
>>> inspect.getargspec(h)
ArgSpec(args=['x'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

Note that a `lambda` produces the exact same object type as a `def funcname():` function statement produces.

What this *doesn't* give you, is what arguments are going to be passed *into the wrapped function*. That's because a function has a more generic use, while `functools.partial()` is specialised and thus can easily provide you with that information. As such, the `partial` tells you that `base=2` will be passed into `int()`, but the `lambda` can only tell you it *receives* an argument `x`.

So, while a `functools.partial()` object can tell you what arguments are going to be passed into what function, a `function` object can only tell you what arguments it receives, as it is the job of the (potentially much more complex) expressions that make up the function *body* to do the call to a wrapped function. And that is ignoring all those functions that don't call other functions at all.